# Determine if a number is prime without using arithmetic

Tags: code-golf, primes, restricted-source

Write a program which determines if a given number is prime.

The catch: No digits or arithmetical operators. This means:

1. No digits from `0` to `9`, anywhere in the program, and whatever the meaning
2. No using any built-in operators for addition (and incrementing), subtraction (and decrementing), multiplication, division, exponentiation, or modulus, anywhere in the program
3. This includes symbols like `+` and functions like `num.add()`
4. All other operations are permitted
5. You may define your own functions for the forbidden operations
6. You may use symbols like `-` when they mean things other than the forbidden operations

Shortest code wins - any language permitted.

## Example solution

An ungolfed solution in Java can be found [here](http://pastie.org/9001717).

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if someone would explain the downvotes.

Comment: Probably because this is impossible? (Without abusing built-in prime functions, that is.)

Comment: Even if not impossible, it is so exclusive of the established techniques for prime detection to be kind of silly ... Feel free to post to [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1412/17546) first to get a feel for how things will turn out _before_ you post.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan I added a solution using a typical prime-detection method.

Comment: Quite similar to [*Is it a prime? w/o math*](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20920/4372)?

Comment: @Ypnypn you should submit your solution as an answer :).

Comment: In light of algorithmshark's solution; Should point two be updated to prohibit built in primality tests?

Comment: Any constraints on performance or size of the primes? i.e. does it matter if the program only supports 31 bit primes or has exponential runtime?

Comment: it is no sense because even if in any programming language it is not used arithmetic, basically any computer will use arithmetic to make any "for" of "if".

Comment: Since we may not use any numbers, are we allowed to use length functions (like ''.length, 'a'.length, 'aa'.length,'aaa'.length for 0 up to 3, for example)?

Comment: @Nate yes; that's okay.

Comment: Does the increment operator also count as addition?

Answer (score 25):

## PHP, 117 characters

This one is based on regular expressions. If a string containing *$n* characters can be split into chunks of equal length, then *$n* must be composite.

(Assumes *$n* is a positive integer.)

```
function p($n){$u=true;$s=str_repeat('x',$n);return($s!='x'&&!preg_match('/^(xx{'.$u.',})\\'.$u.'{'.$u.',}$/U',$s));}
```

#### Output:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) if (p($i)) echo "$i ";

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: I believe this is the epitome of "two problems." +1

Answer (score 15):

### Sage, 18

Looks like this is allowed.

```
input()in Primes()
```

`3` gives `True`, `4` gives `False`

Answer (score 10):

## PERL <s>53</s> <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 48

```perl
('a'x($_=pop))=~/^a?$|^(?<a>aa+?)\g{a}+$/||print
```

Thanks to reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/crmhe/regular_expression_to_check_for_prime_numbers_1111/

Comment: Interesting. However, from the question: "1. No digits from `0` to `9`, anywhere in the program, and whatever the meaning." The variable can be read in a shorter way: `$a=pop;`

Comment: Thanks, any character will do, i used 'a'.. but I need the \1 for the capture. :-S

Comment: A named capture helps: `('a'x($_=pop))=~/^a?$|^(?<a>aa+?)\g{a}+$/||print` (48 bytes)

Comment: Thanks you, I was looking for a short way to use name reference. Also I didn't know the empty print trick. :D

Comment: use of `+` not allowed by rule 3

Comment: @SeanCheshire Rule 3 only seems to disallow using + as an arithmetic operator, not as a regex symbol. This is in contrast to rule 1, which expressly forbids *any* use of digits in any context.

Answer (score 7):

## J - 7 char

Trivial.

```
(p:~=~)
```

This verb is in the form of a hook. Applied to an argument `y`, it will evaluate as follows. (Feel free to check for yourself: [Hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm), [Reflex/Passive](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d220v.htm), [Equals](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d000.htm), [Primes](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dpco.htm).)

```
(p:~=~) y          NB. (F G) y  becomes  y F (G y)   (Hook)
y p:~ (=~ y)       NB. x F~ y   becomes  y F x       (Passive)
(=~ y) p: y        NB. F~ y     becomes  y F y       (Reflex)
(y = y) p: y       NB. anything is equal to itself, so y=y becomes 1
1 p: y             NB. 1 p: y tests for primality of y
```

Usage:

```
   (p:~=~) 5
1
   (p:~=~) 6
0
   (p:~=~) 8675309
1
   NB. test every element of a list
   (p:~=~)every 1627 5231 7610 6311 4549 6990 4220 9028 4066 3496
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I feel that using a built in primality tester goes against the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @Taemyr `(*@{.=*./)@(+.}.@i.)` for 20 char. `+.` is [GCD](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d101.htm), `*.` is [LCM](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d111.htm), `*` is [Signum](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d110.htm). But until the specs change, the 7 char solution is the shortest valid solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 85

```
(lambda i:not any(' '*i==(' '*u)*v for u in range(i)for v in range(i)))(int(input()))
```

Where `*` is not a multiplication operator but a string multiple self-concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 30

```
require'prime';f=->n{n.prime?}
```

Declares a function that returns whether its argument is prime.

Alternative version (same length):

```
require'prime';f=proc &:prime?
```

Obviously bending the rules, but you never said built-in prime functions aren't allowed.

Comment: He shouldn't have to say it: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/1416

Answer (score 3):

## PHP - 208

```
<?php
function i($n){if($n==strlen(" "))return!!"";foreach(range(strlen("  "),$n) as$_){if($_!=$n){$a=array_fill(!!"",$n,"");while(count($a)>=$_)array_splice($a,!!"",$_);if(!count($a))return!!"";}}return!"";}
```

Type juggling in PHP is fun!