# Prime counting function

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

### Introduction

The [Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html), also known as the Pi function \$\pi(x)\$, returns the amount of primes less than or equal to x.

### Challenge

Your program will take an integer x which you can assume to be positive, and output a single integer equal to the amount of primes less than or equal to x. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the winner will be the program with the fewest bytes.

You may use any language of your choosing provided that it existed before this challenge went up, but if the language has a built-in prime-counting function or a primality checking function (such as Mathematica), that function cannot be used in your code.

### Example Inputs

Input:
`1`
Output:
`0`

Input:
`2`
Output:
`1`

Input:
`5`
Output:
`3`

[A000720 - OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000720)

Comment: What about other prime-related functions? For example, "next prime" funciton

Comment: what about prime factorization functions?

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Comment: As Adnan said, welcome to PPCG! For future challenges, let me recommend the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can post a challenge to get meaningful feedback and critique before posting it to the main site.

Comment: I think this is what @TheBikingViking meant to link to: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74269/34718)

Comment: The "no primality checking functions" kept me from posting this elegant Oasis solution: `np+U`

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks, that was what I meant to link to. I've deleted my comment to prevent confusion.

Comment: Can I use isprime ?

Comment: @roslup isprime was explicitly banned.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
!fg
```

This assumes that factorization built-ins are allowed. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IWZn&input=NQ)

#### How it works

```
!    Compute the factorial of the input.
 f   Determine its unique prime factors.
  g  Get the length of the resulting list.
```

Comment: That's really clever!

Comment: Damn, I'm getting rekt in my own language for [the second time](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80934/34388) haha. +1

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @Oliver Because the factorial of **n** is divisible by all integers **1, ..., n** (in particular, the primes **p ≤ n**), and by no other prime **q > n** since it cannot be expressed as a product of smaller numbers.

Comment: `ÅP` is a built-in for getting the list of all prime numbers \$≤n\$. Not that it saves any bytes, but…¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Very neat that builtin-using solutions, [`.Ø>`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9QbOfmYuiQqaSkU@tir6TwqG2SgpK9y3@9wzPs/tvb1f43MjAAAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") and [`ÅPg`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9QbOfmYuiQqaSkU@tir6TwqG2SgpK9y//DrQHp/@3tav8bGRgAAA "05AB1E – Try It Online"), are the same length as this.

Comment: @OliverNi The prime factors of x! cannot include any prime factors > x, since it's only a multiple of numbers <= x. It includes all the prime factors <= x.

Comment: @OliverNi Consider 7! It's 5040. 5040 is, because it's a factorial, divisible by all primes lower than 7, including 7. The next prime above 7 is 11 - it's impossible for 5040 to be divisible by 11, because it wasn't derived by multiplying 11, or any multiple of 11 (which must all be > 11) into it.

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2, 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1,p=1:n/k and p%k+f(n,k+1,p*k*k)
```

Uses the [Wilson's Theorem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260) prime generator. The product `p` tracks `(k-1)!^2`, and `p%k` is 1 for primes and 0 for nonprimes.

Comment: Calculating the factorial from the bottom up is a great trick. +1

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11, 10, 8</s>, 5 bytes

```
:pYFn
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnBZRm4&input=MTU)

I wrote a version that had a really cool explanation of how MATL's matrices work:

[`:YF!s1=1`](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OllGIXMxPTE&inputc=MTU)

But it's no longer relevant. Check out the revision history if you want to see it.

New explanation:

```
:p      % Compute factorial(input)
  YF    % Get the exponenents of prime factorization
    n   % Get the length of the array
```

*Three bytes saved thanks to [Dennis's genius solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94364/31716)*

Comment: It's shorter to use the function "exponents of prime factorization", because that one vectorizes: `YF!s1=s`

Comment: @LuisMendo That's a totally different approach, so feel free to go ahead and post it. (Although if you don't want to, I happily would)

Comment: Go ahead. I'll port that to Jelly to practice :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis!*

```
RÆESL
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsOGRVNM&input=&args=NQ)

Port of [DJMcMayhem's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94354/36398) (former version) refined by Dennis.

```
R          Range of input argument
 ÆE        List of lists of exponents of prime-factor decomposition
   S       Vectorized sum. This right-pads inner lists with zeros
    L      Length of result
```

Comment: Correction: port of Luis Mendo's: DJMcMayhem's MATL answer. :P

Comment: You only need the maximal length of the results of `ÆE`, as each exponent corresponds to a different prime factor. `RÆESL` achieves just that. `!ÆEL` would be even shorter.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks! I've used the first suggestion. The second one is too different, and is your approach

Answer (score 5):

## Retina 0.8.2, <s>31</s> 22 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.+
$*
(?!(..+)\1+$).\B
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLw15RQ09PWzPGUFtFUy/G6f9/QwMA) - Input much larger than 2800 either times out or runs out of memory.

#### References:

[Martin's range generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58682/34718)

[Martin's prime checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57618/34718)

Comment: Can be done in 22 bytes by replacing the last three lines with `(?!(..+)\1+$).\B`. Also makes it less inefficient (can handle inputs up to about 7000). (Also first line should really be `.+`.)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 33 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give the input number on STDIN

`primecount.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=1x$_;$_=s%(?!(11+)\1+$)%%eg-2
```

Gives the wrong result for `0` but that's OK, the op asked for support for positive integers only.

Answer (score 5):

## MediaWiki templates with [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions), 220 + 19 = 239 bytes

```
{{#ifexpr:{{{2}}}+1={{{1}}}|0|{{#ifexpr:{{{3}}}={{{2}}}|{{P|{{{1}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}}+1}}|2}}|{{#ifexpr:{{{2}}} mod {{{3}}}=0|{{#expr:1+{{P|{{{1}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}}+1}}|2}}|{{P|{{{1}}}|{{{2}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}}+1}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

To call the template:

```
{{{P|{{{n}}}|2|2}}}
```

Arranged in Lisp style:

```
{{#ifexpr:{{{2}}} + 1 = {{{1}}}|0|
    {{#ifexpr:{{{3}}} = {{{2}}} |
        {{P|{{{1}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}} + 1}}|2}} |
            {{#ifexpr:{{{2}}} mod {{{3}}} = 0 |
                {{#expr:1 + {{P|{{{1}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}} + 1}}|2}} |
                {{P|{{{1}}}|{{{2}}}|{{#expr:{{{2}}} + 1}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Just a basic primality test from 2 to *n*. The numbers with three braces around them are the variables, where `{{{1}}}` is *n*, `{{{2}}}` is the number being tested, `{{{3}}}` is the factor to check.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, 98 bytes

```
param($n)if($j='001'[$n]){}else{for($i=1;$i-lt$n){for(;'1'*++$i-match'^(?!(..+)\1+$)..'){$j++}}}$j
```

*Caution:* This is **slow** for large input.

Basically the unary-based lookup from [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57636/42963), coupled with a `for` loop and a `$j++` counter. A little additional logic on the front to account for edge cases input `1` and `2`, due to how the fenceposting works in the `for` loops.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13 11 10 9 8 7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

**Using no built-in prime functions whatsoever**
-1 byte thanks to @miles (use a table)
-1 byte thanks to @Dennis (convert from unary to count up the divisors)

```
ḍþḅ1ċ2
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biNw77huIUxxIsy&input=&args=MTA)**
Or see the first 100 terms of the series `n=[1,100]`, also at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4biNw77huIUxxIsyCsKzw4figqw&input=)**

How?

```
ḍþḅ1ċ2 - Main link: n
 þ     - table or outer product, n implicitly becomes [1,2,3,...n]
ḍ      - divides
  ḅ1   - Convert from unary: number of numbers in [1,2,3,...,n] that divide x
                             (numbers greater than x do not divide x)
    ċ2 - count 2s: count the numbers in [1,2,3,...,n] with exactly 2 divisors
                   (only primes have 2 divisors: 1 and themselves)
```

Comment: You can get to 7 bytes ```%þ`¬Sċ2``` using a table of remainders.

Comment: `ḍþḅ1ċ2` saves a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
f=(n,x=n)=>n>1&&(--x<2)+(n%x?f(n,x):f(n-1))
```

A modification of my <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 33-byte primality function (1 byte saved by @Neil, 2 by @Arnauld):

```
f=(n,x=n)=>n>1&--x<2||n%x&&f(n,x)
```

(I can't post this anywhere because [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/42545) only accepts full programs...)

#### Test snippet

```js
f=(n,x=n)=>n>1&&(--x<2)+(n%x?f(n,x):f(n-1))
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="console.log('f('+this.value+') is '+f(this.value))" value=2>
```

Comment: Waw...it took me a while to understand. Nice job!

Comment: Sadly it doesn't apply to your answer but you can probably get away with one `&` in the middle of your primality function.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
!Æv
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=IcOGdg&input=&args=)

#### How it works

```
!Æv  Main link. Argument: n

!    Compute the factorial of n.
 Æv  Count the number of distinct prime factors.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Assumes that prime factorization builtins are allowed.

Code:

```
LÒ1ùg
```

Explanation:

```
L      # Get the range [1, ..., input]
 Ò     # Prime factorize each with duplicates
  1ù   # Keep the elements with length 1
    g  # Get the length of the resulting array
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TMOSMcO5Zw&input=NQ)

Comment: `ÅPg` is what it'd be now, right?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḷ!²%RS
```

This uses only basic arithmetic and Wilson's theorem. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2IcKyJVJT&input=&args=MTAw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bi2IcKyJVJTCsW8w4figqxH&input=&args=MSwgMiwgNQ).

#### How it works

```
Ḷ!²%RS  Main link. Argument: n

Ḷ       Unlength; yield [0, ..., n - 1].
 !      Factorial; yield [0!, ..., (n - 1)!].
  ²     Square; yield [0!², ..., (n - 1)!²].
    R   Range; yield [1, ..., n].
   %    Modulus; yield [0!² % 1, ..., (n - 1)!² % n].
        By a corollary to Wilson's theorem, (k - 1)!² % k yields 1 if k is prime
        and 0 if k is 1 or composite.
     S  Sum; add the resulting Booleans.
```

Answer (score 3):

## C# 5.0 <strike>78</strike> 77

```
int F(int n){int z=n;if(n<2)return 0;for(;n%--z!=0;);return(2>z?1:0)+F(n-1);}
```

Ungolfed

```
int F(int n)
{
    var z = n;
    if (n < 2) return 0;
    for (; n % --z != 0;) ;
    return F(n - 1) + (2 > z ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: @tfbninja yes you right, but I gave the function part only, which does not compile by it's own

Comment: @tfbninja [Actually, it's not.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6912/41024)

Comment: cool sounds good!

Answer (score 3):

## Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE), 32 bytes

```
((?=(\2?+x*?(?!(xx+)\3+$))xx)x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7dSsMwGL3fU8QRlnxLu6YVb0yzdjBvvfLOjjBlg0DcalIhEuKlD@Aj@iI1q4I3h@87nL/@YM3N@PKOsBUomPPz3iBciPTKert52Kzj7Hi2FDvJRb0WEJA@pg9Cb/VpQPPuNBcRtUa63uiBkpxk7u3JDcmisrzMSji8XkTNP8sTD7dYgbhkudS4t62pKwiteSx3MiHfiThDaGrWfwTWtZwE6WIMQvJS4onHGuRHgW0BAbvFYto1zUqbS/E7E@sVQd@fX4isaMtSWt7mCUHEGJW6u98qNVLaSNpVDfPLhjZX1HsG3TXDAN6Dh@U48rzi/Ac) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLbtswELz7KzZCA5OyzcjprYxgtEULFGjaIjk6PtASZTOhKJWkYjlBrv2AfmJ/xF3K7CNAdFnt7nCWM9xbcS9mt@XdQdVtYz3cYs5Uw1IO/1c6r/SLNSs3ssfOqO3WWhVQaOEcXApl4BFizXnhMdw3qoQaO@TaW2U2IOzGLVcU/NY2Owcf@kK2XjV4cgTwUWkJVW7kbvglCSuaUjLsJ5S/66pKWlleSVFKC@sB9rxI/pyMaUUpj3Pd1PPdNvAT4vI1ahDlZ2UkofQkN53WVFXEMfm9E9qR5CxN04TSx@fQIwMh/kWCR2TwfxmQ4AwZ1oi7426Sj2/MOETPn461p2/Ce2kN2Dz@odq6DQMc5ejGumm0FAYe8goZJYfrQhiD0pVpOw85BLWxRq73zsuaKUM5RJ0DjG2F@yJ7j9ccLAaIhmi8O3IcQQYRUWLsL1egsR1QzLVaeZLM8BEQ78Fk2PlkPK6BZa2wTmJC9DJb0SmY@YtNpqXZ@O3FOSwgIOENhvkKGYutsMtVH/UMmZmvOLy1Vuwdq5TWpJ@O@/FgCkDV2KANr5GbjIO5yM0cw2SCAi@FL7boUI1sltXHjAyba3DB3yP5cWPYzoqWxBFF0@6/VlfCbCROyqaG0qC0AlLjeFOid@FtH2g0uUHHdlZ5ScKjUv6Qe9uF9/nXbtFDX5HktIRfP37CaZmgM1Oo2cY2XUsyGv1Aav4UvlHYuAMhi5zcnC8mfbogixPS9xN683ryitK@pz1ND2GrDtnsPMt@Aw) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDNatwwEL7nKaZC4Jm11ut105ZFa3xpC4HSQ9NbHITjamNTWxayAoaQax@gj9gX2Y6X9NLDDPP3fd/M@M6fj5XvPMgAJYidgAx8sI8mWD80rcVkl20qY7pmiKadRt8PNtRYk66/7eZEQcJ24qJ5tOuAi9bFGY35fPPlkzGkYE9MycQaeteb2UYUvg02e2janzGwM0M/9lEoENfF4frw/kNxeCdIX52mgLIvcy2H8sTsM95@/3jzlTQ9Q39COdzNMQzWcUTb/X1ZitoJ4uH56YE7XFa52u5pxdvFD9MPi2IrFI9rxrfTk4sr9lgw6I4J2Of3@grgouxec@mO5aXPUZoSSwNePjQ2se1QBsVi67tsEzFZEiUdKTkSwfO6ZU@27aZ1NQ18zV7DmoN0mYA/v36DyP5dMbIa6ZeX/56NpM@IVYl1UaXLpsLqDS5LSvXbVBItCy20OZ/zbZHnfwE) - PCRE

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the length of the match.

```
        # tail = N = input value; no anchor needed, as every value returns a match
# Count the number of primes <= N, from the largest to the smallest prime.
(       # J = 0
    (?=
        # \2 starts at zero, and on each subsequent iteration, contains the difference
        # N-P-(J-1) where P is the previously found prime, and J is the running total of
        # our prime count.
        (
            \2?+           # Start from the previous value of \2, atomically so that it
                           # can't be backtracked and started again from zero if the
                           # following fails to match. This will make tail = P-1, where
                           # P is the previously found prime.
            x*?            # Advance as little as necessary to make the following match,
                           # and add this to \2, while subtracting it from tail.
            (?!(xx+)\3+$)  # Assert tail is not composite; note that this needs to be
                           # inside group \2 for it to work in PCRE1 and older versions of
                           # PCRE2, which atomicize groups that have nested backreferences
        )
        xx                 # Assert tail is prime by eliminating the false positives 0, 1
    )
    x   # J += 1; tail -= 1
)*      # Iterate zero or more times, until there are no more smaller primes
# Return J as our match
```

## Regex (Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
((?=(?=(\3?))(\2x*?(?!(xx+)\4+$))xx)x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NTsMwEIX3OcVgIXUmf4pTVglWDpJmEYHbGjlOZBvhXoADcEQuEuwikGbx5ud987abv67muKtlW60Hd3OllRcZyje3mh6ssIyxHXEQqU7HgQhPbcgHHB4whIJOT8UjUQgUKN/j7ci7ik89KNFk59WCBmUStnb@VZkuAy107TatPLKKUQbqDFoa1PTcdqBHPgk9NlMGyWyS2c7mIlEZj2lB5a/iExWcIg8WcU9cOznblyvaElhguYnoxF7SSRKqg80mL/X3ieD9X6713dcfVnmJzls0VBzg@/MLDkVql5h2NkjxY/WvYw7am6ptmh8) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BasMwEEX3OcXEhFrj2EJ2u4orjGlM6SaFtDs7mJYojkAoRnGIuumyB@gRexFXdtrAMPAf/898c3r/6A1wWItG2JZqcYZl/ppTI9624QUuFk@Pq@d18ZC/FClIzlI476USoHgjuqNDO1BlFG849yrtpY6rklEaJZsUhN6OgB5bJTviRz5eAlQJ3XR7gveJM5Qu7UKXwARgdzCgQWoYIO0OtSQxQ0oH41WOh4hnvUAj8E8wI5DToWF7GpqN3yWPnTZSd6BDH36@vsEPZzfXAn@2/zWp62K1rOuekIwPU91miKRKbJCRbEqsnWN1N58hWosWg75nUcLYLw) - Ruby

This is a port of the Perl/Java/PCRE regex to flavors that have no support for nested backreferences. Python's built-in `re` module does not even support forward backreferences, so for Python this requires [`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/).

```
        # tail = N = input value; no anchor needed, as every value returns a match
# Count the number of primes <= N, from the largest to the smallest prime.
(       # J = 0
    (?=
        # \2 starts at zero, and on each subsequent iteration, contains the difference
        # N-P-(J-1) where P is the previously found prime, and J is the running total of
        # our prime count.
        (?=(\3?))          # \2 = \3 (or 0 if \3 is unset), to make up for the lack of
                           #      nested backreferences
        (
            \2             # Start from the previous value of \3 (as copied into \2).
                           # This will make tail = P-1, where P is the previously found
                           # prime.
            x*?            # Advance as little as necessary to make the following match,
                           # and add this to \3, while subtracting it from tail.
            (?!(xx+)\4+$)  # Assert tail is not composite; note that this needs to be
                           # inside group \3 for it to work in PCRE1 and older versions of
                           # PCRE2, which atomicize groups that have nested backreferences
        )
        xx                 # Assert tail is prime by eliminating the false positives 0, 1
    )
    x   # J += 1; tail -= 1
)*      # Iterate zero or more times, until there are no more smaller primes
# Return J as our match
```

## Regex (.NET), 35 bytes

```
((?=((?>\2?)x*?(?!(xx+)\3+$))xx)x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHNTuswEIX39yncCqke8qOk7DBukSIWSCCubpFYAAuTToslx4lsp5gGtvcBeERepLhJYYMlS2PNsec7x6VNytrgTosKbSNKJItX67DqWiv1mhS8qLWtFbLhfIvepf9w3SphLnxj0FoZBKxUwlpSddYJJ0uyqeWSXAupCYVuIwyx/Hy8o3TOw549TOfgj@d0PqLeR/BwEh0BeA8ejndjtpcbrvGFhDnoqU0X7ZN1JoyneWzTK9Rr95xMIe77N43bE6RFXTVS4RLYoCWKrWpDpXZE84xRxYsALpZXUiMFGHHdKsU0z6GTK6pnGRTpnZEOB0GP0XCVLholHZ0kE2D7t2SM7E@40Bw4ZtO3t1FopLfm9a8wFmlznz3GdRuk8Lv1fS3JBw3C91g6vtQboUJuRug1npIuex/HChgqi32Gvg9lMSQx8ZNYwo/FbbAozzgyGUWxj3hoQ3ctXPlMKm7SvqI@WFjRKuRZluHjeuPbX8a3PGc/TAGCfP7/IF0eYPwBPq4OBbD3Ye2yZJplXw)

This is a direct port of the Perl/Java/PCRE regex.

## Regex (.NET), 35 bytes

```
^(?=(x*?(?!(xx+)\2+$)x)*x)(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFNbtswEIX3PQVtFPBM9APJyzK0CwhdFEjQog7QRX8AVh47BChKICmXsZJtD9Aj9iIuLTnZhKsh5g3ne4@1y@rW0snIhlwna2KbB@epGXqnzJ5VomqNazXx6X5HwedfaN9raT@EzpJzKgp4raVzrBmcl17V7NCqLbuVyjDA4SAtc@L9/PQT1gLC1RrWMwghwe/L5C0GvAoI6@usXMXyNOdnuRWGfrO4hwK4fNP/ct7G9VCmLr8hs/f32RLTsf@p82eCvGqbTmnaIp@0TPNda0EZz4woOGhRRXC5vVGGAHEmTK81N6LEQe3ArAqs8q9WeZoEI0YndL7ptPKwyBbIz2@plPibONBdOFbLx8dZbOR39uGztI6g@1b8SNs@SvF163ksKycN4fNamH80B6ljblaaPb1jQ/E0TzVy0o7GDMMYymZKYhEWqcIXi8doUV0L4ipJ0pCI2MbhVvr6njXC5mMFIVrYQRPzrOv4caPx4yvjR1HyF6YIwf79@cuGMsKEC3zaXArkT9M5ldmyKP4D)

This uses the .NET feature of balanced groups to do the counting. It does not return a value for zero, but doing so only requires +1 byte (**36 bytes**):

```
^(?=(x*?(?!(xx+)\2+$)x)*x|)(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHPTuMwEMbvPIVbIdVD/ijpEeN2pYgDEmhXFIkD7EredFosOU5kO8U07XUfYB@RFyluUrjg01jzjef3fS5tUtYGD1pUaBtRIlm8WYdV11qp16TgRa1trZAN9wf0Lr3HdauEufaNQWtlELBSCWtJ1VknnCzJppZLciekJhS6jTDE8h/jwx8659RfzOl8RL2P4HkanYOHC78DOr9K8lmoD2N21Buu8ZWEReipTRftX@tM2E/z2Ka3qNfuJZlC3Pd/Nu6IkBZ11UiFS2CDlii2qg2V2hHNM0YVLwK5WN5KjRRgxHWrFNM8h06uqJ5lUKSPRjocBD1Gw1W6aJR0dJJMgB3fkjGyszDQnDhm091uFBrpg3n7JYxF2jxlv@O6DVL43vocS/JBg/C5lo5v9EaoEJwReo2XpMv241gBQ2WxD9H3oSyGJCZ@Ekv4srgNFuUVRyajKPYRD23o7oQrX0jFTdpX1AcLK1qFPMsy/FxvfPvN@Jbn7IspQJD3f/9JlwcYf4KPq1MBbD@cQ5ZMs@wD)

```
^                      # tail = N = input number
(?=
    (
        x*?            # Advance as little as necessary to make the following match
        (?!(xx+)\3+$)  # Assert tail is not composite
        x              # Eliminate the false primality positive of 0, and advance forward
                       # so that the next prime can be found (if we didn't do this, the
                       # regex engine would exit the loop due to a zero-width match)
    )*                 # Every time this loop matches an iteration, the capture group 1
                       # match is pushed onto the stack. This (balanced groups) is how we
                       # count the number of primes.
    x                  # Eliminate the false primality positive of 1
|                      # Allow us to return a value of 0 for N=0
)
(?<-1>x)*              # Pop all of the group 2 captures off the stack, doing head += 1
                       # for each one. This gives us our return value match.
```

---

I strongly suspect this function is impossible to implement in ECMAScript regex, even with the addition of `(?*)` or `(?<=)` / `(?<!)`. There doesn't seem to be room to multiplex the count and the current prime into a single tail variable, but I [don't know if this can be proved](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/137112/what-can-be-proven-regarding-the-differences-in-power-between-unary-ecmascript-r).

Only one variable can be modified within a loop, such that must decrease by at least 1 on every step – and only \$O(n)\$ space is available; no variable may contain a value larger than \$n\$, and the language has no concept of arrays (although it is possible to take them as immutable input), only scalar variables (i.e. capture groups and the cursor position).

So it would seem that calculating this function would require \$O({n^2\over log(n)})\$ scratch space, to multiplex the iteration count and current prime into a single number. While multiple loops in a row would be able to get closer to \$\pi(n)\$ than a single loop, the number of such loops could only be a constant; it seems that it would need to be able to grow with \$n\$ to be able to actually asymptotically calculate \$\pi(n)\$. And a nested loop would still have to distill all the information gained by its innermost loop into a single number \$\le n\$.

But these things are just indications and vague evidence, not a proof. I have [set a bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21941/17216) regarding this open question.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
SmPs}l
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=SmPs%7Dl&input=5)

Thanks to Maltysen for new algorithm

```
SmP    -    map(factorise, input)
   s   -   sum(^)
    }  -  uniquify(^)
     l - len(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Since others are using prime factorization functions...

```
l{sPMS
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BsPMS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A5%0A100&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 30

```bash
seq $1|factor|egrep -c :.\\S+$
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/VwKgoN)

---

## Bash + coreutils + BSD-games package, 22

```bash
primes 1 $[$1+1]|wc -l
```

This shorter answer requires that you have the bsdgames package installed: `sudo apt install bsdgames`.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 157 bytes

```
n=>{int c=0,i=1,j;bool f;for(;i<=n;i++){if(i==1);else if(i<=3)c++;else if(i%2==0|i%3==0);else{j=5;f=1>0;while(j*j<=i)if(i%j++==0)f=1<0;c+=f?1:0;}}return c;};
```

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, int> s = n =>
            {
                int c = 0, i = 1, j;
                bool f;
                for (; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 1) ;
                    else if (i <= 3) c++;
                    else if (i % 2 == 0 | i % 3 == 0) ;
                    else
                    {
                        j = 5;
                        f = 1 > 0;
                        while (j * j <= i)
                            if (i % j++ == 0)
                                f = 1 < 0;
                        c += f ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                }
                return c;
            };

        Console.WriteLine("1 -> 0 : " + (s(1) == 0 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("2 -> 1 : " + (s(2) == 1 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("5 -> 3 : " + (s(5) == 3 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("10 -> 4 : " + (s(10) == 4 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("100 -> 25 : " + (s(100) == 25 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("1,000 -> 168 : " + (s(1000) == 168 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("10,000 -> 1,229 : " + (s(10000) == 1229 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("100,000 -> 9,592 : " + (s(100000) == 9592 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
        Console.WriteLine("1,000,000 -> 78,498 : " + (s(1000000) == 78498 ? "OK" : "FAIL"));
    }
}
```

Starts to take awhile once you go above 1 million.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆRL
```

Jelly has a built-in prime counting function, `ÆC` and a prime checking function, `ÆP`, this instead uses a built-in prime generating function, `ÆR` and takes the length `L`.

I guess this is about as borderline as using prime factorisation built-ins, which would also take 3 bytes with `!Æv` (`!` factorial, `Æv` count prime factors)

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 60 bytes

Continuing my attachment to one-line Matlab functions. Without using a factorisation built-in:

```
f=@(x) nnz(arrayfun(@(x) x-2==nnz(mod(x,[1:1:x])),[1:1:x]));
```

Given that a prime `y` has only two factors in `[1,y]`: we count the numbers in the range `[1,x]` which have only two factors.

Using factorisation allows for significant shortening (down to 46 bytes).

```
g=@(x) size(unique(factor(factorial(x))),2);
```

Conclusion: Need to look into them golfing languages :D

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

This avoids prime-factor decomposition. Its complexity is O(*n*²).

```
:t!\~s2=s
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnQhXH5zMj1z&input=NTA)

```
:     % Range [1 2 ... n] (row vector)
t!    % Duplicate and transpose into a column vector
\     % Modulo with broadcast. Gives matrix in which entry (i,j) is i modulo j, with
      % i, j in [1 2 ... n]. A value 0 in entry (i,j) means i is divisible by j
~     % Negate. Now 1 means i is divisible by j
s     % Sum of each column. Gives row vector with the number of divisors of each j
2=    % Compare each entry with 2. A true result corresponds to a prime
s     % Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>96</s> 92 bytes

```
for($j=$argv[1]-1;$j>0;$j--){$p=1;for($i=2;$i<$j;$i++)if(is_int($j/$i))$p=0;$t+=$p;}echo $t;
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Roman Gräf

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f2572d44a90f3d1e3c4d0b9f0bf839c102b97ea8)

Ungolfed testing code:

```
$argv[1] = 5;

for($j=$argv[1]-1;$j>0;$j--) {
    $p=1;
    for($i=2;$i<$j;$i++) {
        if(is_int($j/$i)) {
            $p=0;
        }
    }
    $t+=$p;
}
echo $t;
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7278074256589459c294fdeb1f7dc791acec6bb)

Comment: Why do you use `isInt(...)?1:0` and not just `isInt(...)`

Comment: @RomanGräf Thanks, you are right. I left the ternary after a lot of code semplification, and that was so obvious that I couldn't see it...

Answer (score 2):

## Actually, 10 bytes

This was the shortest solution I found that didn't run into interpreter bugs on TIO. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O-KVl3JgUOKVnD5g4paRbA&input=MzA)

```
;╗r`P╜>`░l
```

**Ungolfing**

```
         Implicit input n.
;╗       Duplicate n and save a copy of n to register 0.
r        Push range [0..(n-1)].
`...`░   Push values of the range where the following function returns a truthy value.
  P        Push the a-th prime
  ╜        Push n from register 0.
  >        Check if n > the a-th prime.
l        Push len(the_resulting_list).
         Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>95</s> 84 bytes

```java
z->{int c=0,n=2,i,x;for(;n<=z;c+=x>1?1:0)for(x=n++,i=2;i<x;x=x%i++<1?0:x);return c;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZDBasMwEETv@Yq9FCTkGMvQS2QlX9Bccgw9qIpSNnXWRpaD4uBvd2U315LLwM5bmGEu5mbWTevocvqZbG26Dj4M0mMFgBScPxvrYD@fiwGWzTpwlZxxlaQLJqCFPRBomIb19rG86SIjXWaYRXVuPFNU6UFZoeNW7uSm4LMZNQmRoS4VVlFFHd9QiEruik3kyrvQewKrxknNOW3/VaecZ9ytwRNcU1F2CB7p@/hp@F/Jw70L7po3fcjbREJNjHLLJF8q/8vLF/z9BZcFf24yTr8)

```java
z->{                // Method with integer parameter and integer return-type
  int c=0,          //  Start the counter at 0
      n=2,          //  Starting prime is 2
      i,x;          //  Two other temp integers
  for(;n<=z;        //  Loop (1) as long as `n` is smaller than or equal to the input `z`
       c+=x>1?1:0)  //    and increase the counter if we've came across a prime
                    //    (if `x` is larger than 0, it means the current `n` is a prime)
     for(x=n++,i=2;i<x;x=x%i++<1?0:x);
                    //   Determine if the next integer in line is a prime by setting `x`
                    //   (and increase `n` by 1 afterwards)
                    //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return c;         //  Return the resulting counter
}                   // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
2+.=0+.=⍳∘.|⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wQjbT1bAyB@1Lv5UccMvRogDZQ4tMJQwUjBFAA)

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices 1…N
 ⧽ `∘.|` remainder-table (using those two as axes)
`⍳` **ɩ**ndices 1…N

`0+.=` the sum of the elements equal to zero (i.e. how many dividers does each have)

`2+.=` the sum of the elements equal to two (i.e. how many primes are there)

Comment: Another approach    {⍴(⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳⍵}

Comment: @AndrewOgden Ooh, that actually comes out shorter: `(≢⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳` ― Do you want to post that, it being a completely different approach?

Comment: I would, but it's not my algorithm. https://youtu.be/Gsj_7tFtODk?t=600

Comment: @AndrewOgden I know. I came up with it in '97 :-) Go ahead and post!

Comment: Lol, you're a legend.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
(≢⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳
 ≢ ⍝ tally
  ⊢~ ⍝ index values not in matrix of composite numbers
    ∘.×⍨ ⍝ outer product of positive integers with themselves
        1↓⍳ ⍝ range from 1–n less the first element
```

h/t [@adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%C3%A1m)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNR52LHnUtqnvUMUPv8PRHvSs0DR@1TX7UuxkorWDAlaZgCMRGQGwKxJbmQMLYwMAAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 49 bytes

```c
p(n,i){for(i=n;--i&&n%i;);return--n?p(n)+!--i:0;}
```

Assumes `n` is positive.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYzBDoIwEAXP7VesJJBuYBPFmyv6I14IiHmJLqRBL4Rvr73OTGaQ4d3bK6UlWAPepjkGdKYiqCoroazxuX6jidg9N1wfsrocdU@w1X96WPjNGNlv3mVCUO/yhAKoo5MS6ErnVqmuwd65JeZoCkUp7Uhyo3J8WNEQGloCmNXv6Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```
FAFL
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_UXTsgqWlJWm6FkvcHN18IEyoyIKFphAGAA)

Port of Dennis's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
F       # Push the factorial of the input
 AF     # Get the unique prime factors
   L    # Push the length of the list
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>50+2</s> <s>46+2</s> 43 bytes

Saved <s>3</s> 5 bytes thanks to Neil:

```js
f=n=>n&&eval(`for(z=n;n%--z;);1==z`)+f(n-1)
```

`eval` can access the `n` parameter.
The `eval(...)` checks if `n` is prime.

---

**Previous solutions:**
Byte count should be +2 because I forgot to name the function `f=` (needed for recursion)

46+2 bytes (Saved 3 bytes thanks to ETHproductions):

```js
n=>n&&eval(`for(z=n=${n};n%--z;);1==z`)+f(n-1)
```

50+2 bytes:

```js
n=>n&&eval(`for(z=${n};${n}%--z&&z;);1==z`)+f(n-1)
```

Comment: At least on my browser, `eval` can access the `n` parameter to your function (which you forgot to name, costing you 2 bytes; it's good to know that I'm not the only one who makes that mistake) which saves you 5 bytes.

Comment: @Neil I didn't know for `eval`. Tested with firefox, chrome and edge it worked for me. The explanation is [eval() parses in statement context](http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html). Two examples: `a=12;f=b=>eval('a + 5');f(8)` displays `17` and `a=12;f=a=>eval('a + 5');f(8)` displays `13`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7,102 bytes

**Brute force**

```
int f(int n){int i=2,j=2,c=1,t=0;for(;i<=n;j=2,c+=t==1?1:0,i++)for(;j<i;t=i%j++==0?j=i+1:1);return c;}
```

## Ungolfed

```
int f(int n){
int i=2,j=2,c=1,t=0;
for(;i<=n;j=2,c+=t==1?1:0,i++)
    for(;j<i;)
        t=i%j++==0?j=i+1:1;
    return c;
 }
```

Comment: This is currently giving an incorrect result for input `1`. It currently returns `1` instead of `0`. You can fix this by either changing `return c;` to `return n<2?0:c;` or changing `,c=1,` to `,c=n<2?0:1,`.

Answer (score 1):

## q 35 bytes

```
{sum 1=sum'[0=2_' a mod\: a:til x]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Actually, 10 bytes

If my first Actually answer is disallowed for using a prime-generating function, here is a backup answer using Wilson's theorem. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=UmA7RCHCsiVgTc6j&input=MzA)

```
R`;D!²%`MΣ
```

**Try it online**

```
         Implicit input n.
R        Push range [1..n]
`...`M   Map the following function over the range. Variable k.
  ;        Duplicate k.
  D        Decrement one of the copies of k.
  !²       Push ((k-1)!)².
  %        Push ((k-1)!)² % k. This returns 1 if k is prime, else 0.
Σ        Sums the result of the map, adding all the 1s that represent primes, 
          giving the total number of primes less than n.
         Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 60 bytes

```
(require math)(λ(n)(length(filter prime?(range 1(+ 1 n)))))
```

Testing:

```
(require math)
(define f
    (λ(n) (length (filter prime? (range 1 (+ 1 n)))))
)

(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 3)
(f 5)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: If `(require math)` is required for your program to work, you need to include it in your byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, 15 bytes

```
n->#factor(n!)~
```

Take the factorial and count its unique prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

## Actually, 3 bytes

This uses a prime factorization function, which may or may not be allowed after the OP clarifies. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=IXls&input=NA)

```
!yl
```

**Ungolfing**

```
     Implicit input n.
!    Push n factorial.
 y   Push a list of all of the positive prime factors of n! (every prime < n)
  l  Take the length of that list of primes.
     Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
řṗƩ
```

Explanation:

```
ř         Push [1,2,...,input]
 ṗ        Elementwise isPrime(k)
  Ʃ       Sum of array (autoconverts booleans to 0/1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MyHO6cfW/n/v6ERAA)

Comment: So one can use isprime right?

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 31 bytes

```
{+grep {$_%%none 2..^$_},2..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoHa@QcH2f7V2elFqgUK1Sryqal5@XqqCkZ5enEp8rQ6QBlL/ixMrFc43aBhqWitAmUYIpqmm9X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## (pure) BASH, 138 bytes

Look, Mom!
No preloaded prime tables, no prime related builtins, not even a division or plultimication!

```
a=2
l=0
while((a<=$1));do if((b[a]))
then((c=b[a]));else((c=a,l++));fi;((d=a+c))
while((b[d]));do((d+=c));done
((b[d]=c,a++));done;echo $l
```

Eating the pudding:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 11033 ; do bash fsoe-primecounter-in-bash $i ; done
0
1
2
1337
```

Ok, probably looping while looking at candidates modulo all possible divisors would have been shorter in "pure BASH" too but we've seen those loops at least 1001 times now.

This solution builds its own prime table on the fly and so is bearably fast even in "pure BASH".

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:1if n<1else(2**n%n==2)+f(n-1)
```

An odd integer k is prime if an only if 2**(k-1) is congruent to 1 mod k. Thus, we just check for this condition and add 1 for the case of k=2.

Comment: 2**n % n==2 is not enough as primaly test

Comment: @RosLuP That is why the base case of n==0 should add 1 (to account for the n=2 case).

Comment: 2**n % n==2 is not enough in general... Exist many (infinite in what I would remember) numbers where 2^n%n=2 that are *not* primes

Comment: For example 341=11*31 but ( 2^341) mod 341==2

Comment: @RosLuP: Ah ok yes, I looked it up. These numbers are called Fermat Psuedoprimes but they appear to be quite rare :P

Answer (score 1):

## APL NARS, 150 bytes

```
∇r←g n;h;i;k
i←0⋄h←1+⍳n-1⋄→B
A:k←i⊃h⋄h←k∪(0≠k∣h)/h
B:→A×⍳(⍴h)≥i+←1
r←⍴h
∇
```

this would be the "Crivello di Eratostene" or something as that.

If h=2..n

In the first  iteration of the loop eliminate each multiple of 2 in h except 2

in the second iteration of the loop eliminate each multiple of 3 in h except 3

...

return the number of final element of h.(in h primes return ⍴h)

```
  g¨1 2 5
0  1  3 
  g 20000
2262
```

As note negative for the question: There would be a range limit for the arg of the function; something as 1..20000 and each answer would indicate the range the argument has to be for to be safe to pass to the function (without one seg fault in the code, without one memory insufficient for the program, without one incorrect value return as result )

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
l{P.!Q
```

Explanation follows:

```
   .!Q Factorial of input
  P    List primes of factorial with multiplicity
 {     Remove duplicates formed by said multiplicity
l      Length of deduplicated list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 17 bytes

```
L,RB*f0b]@bLA1=!*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ8hJK80gKdYhycfR0FZR679KTmJuUkqigqGdgoIhp7WCAZc/F7KYKVDMGFXM0AAoZsLl/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 85 bytes

```
{n:Int->var r=0
for(i in 2..n){var t=1
for(p in 2..i/2)if(i%p==0){t--
break}
r+=t}
r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVti9tGEP6uXzEJTSMRW5Z9ub6YKnBcEzhIuND0Sz@upZW9WNpVdld@wRj6D/uTrjOzki4xuNDjMJZ2duaZ53lmvDW@VvppNoN7K4WXJXgDbS2OsFd@A36jHBQbUddSr@UywriN961bzmaFKeXa1FXqvCi28oBRGJIWppl97aTzymg3@/XtzdtfZq1VjZwWptNe6fW06nRBx5TtQXtryi4804s/NxI@Uzzc9/HwoY@fgKidga02ew3CITgMVTCkg3/@jg/JBKz0ndXhWDSUBEwFjMFBLR2dCA3GgvzaiZoaPqRU@n7ok4H8ZTqLt8zaigbJqDFQbDGjBqW9XEsLB9hvVLGBo@mgEATJdYgb860ktMYpr3YSQesSTOfbzoMAhw3VckwxIvhfYJEklAX/BZAKU5LhWaUJuJBvr7TGGowdEdGr535YXAmV3KNWsDp66dKhb2hQ/85Rs0eoUdZOrCXhOhInxcYYaoOS7VRJltkID8qDPChHFlrJylh5YR7YS2yuayewQiZUxeXH5BtB3aw6Vfup0vC9Y54lRh4EH4pa@SMml8X2u4DYdagIJvskMH8jvCoEeoIRjkEoljaeOMEmSxSjbwy5ZCO8P4imRZUeNIrmouBT/Mr@n9PHI@vJz9nF@eLifH5xfntxfsPnd1mW/bzIYAqP7x@@RAFFi9ZBfDtpHTdffdOCoRPssxbNqhRpGuERMGGx7pqVtEuarYQ/4RRFAJjyd1mJrvbkIm00NguwExYnxtHbnHrhuA/IM8ljaaShsqaBxeDSkB1NJiWpqPxrFy6xZpQSxYdYIfQDUbtI03AlCTA49i6MCnqGXcxX@8HhHmSZciih82TQnHjsL19Dh04Lrio6a9FsQzyOolOrWoYyE0JNxjYc3EAlCh8yXr3gyTKv/TfwaMbQ7mMNKhvGrTamDeCZh7AHjO6pYFpmi4QDgKAEpl6NcTnKQFRB/0ftT6fj4wrX9LZ/OlNlVT2zWpb9lBOdjDQg6QV@k3O2qL@J@Hq9/@CVGUjlULoW9mj/IuIbnDKsaRKltLjg0Ghr6WmSbO8NmlLaHvMJLCZwO4H5HH5kq2fBpo1QOhZ27ZZwZ604/vbFW5zid8lo1I/samS4xfKD@UW9NhYXV0NiO7HDCj8NmytYZVwY@dNJL9H503fs7zyLsNlYDX5MTmysfM6v20Eb1EVVsXrV5nmWnIh1Zvsc2Te5x8/z00CXwNkbuqX9jquwoGWtmDlvj72AqIT2tY5f/nAasMWYsvyotIyTFy9SbxBlnCTnl0nf@qPGtgvZhl@8IbEzqGjZj28ozF2f0ZkeN17sl/irYM1eoG@T/6g@p1LAe@tayGIImV8NuR1Cbq4XGivdXo25ycZS2eBKJC@YjVwSPf0L)

Try lambda for first time as saved 16 bytes.

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 101 bytes

```
fun c(n:Int):Int{var r=0
for(i in 2..n){var t=1
for(p in 2..i/2)if(i%p==0){t--
break}
r+=t}
return r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXbbttGEH3nV0yCpiERiaLkGG2FqoDhJoCBBimavvRxRS7FhchdZndoSTAM9A/7Se7MLCk3dvJQwyBMzmXPnHNmvXfYGvuwWMC11wp1Beigb9UJDgYbwMYEKBvVttru9DqhvAaxD@vFonSV3rm2zgOqcq@PlEUpeem6xedBBzTOhsVPby/e/rjoven0vHSDRWN383qwJYe5241F76ohvvOHPxsNv3M@XI/58H7Mn4Fqg4O9dQcLKhA4SjUwtYN//k6P2Qy8xsHbGFYdNwFXg2AI0OrAEWXBedCfB9XywMecj76e5hQgf7nBU5XbedURGS0lqj11tGAs6p32cIRDY8oGTm6AUjGkMBBu6rfV0Ltg0NxqAm0rcAP2A4KCQAO1@tzijOB/gSWSSBb6VcAqzFmGR5VmEGK/g7GWzhDshIg/Pc4j4mqo9YG0gu0JdcinuaEj/YfAw56gJVkHtdOM68SclI1zPAY3uzUVW6ZRCAZBH01gC2117bx@Yh44aBpu6GewJSZMLcefmzeKp9kOpsW5sfClYx4lJh6UBFVr8ETNdbn/IiENAylCzT4o6t8pNKUiTwjCcxKJZR0yJzRkRWKMgxGXYoR3R9X1pNKNJdFCEn1Kf4r/l/z4KHrKe/EkvnoSXz6JXz6JX0j8qiiKH1YFzOHju5tPUlcsoywPhBvK1K5pVzJ@3N0qD35TJMRyahj@Ks9tJp9xs5TP/fjZLFaZqVPzqt9siuwO5/NkS4u@v0/8mw3SU5YF/P1DHLwntxIlt9oH3kg5mlVI7dBttV@DgOAn3CUJABX9qms1tMjWtM4SgwACUAf@umGCJO89iceae74noPaug9Vk/didnKs1W8Pg6xCLxAjckoaC1BC44zSwlGQRhuRexf0jI8pqSOm4jTKDrnJJFZ7Y9RsWZyz@Fjqyb7RqOXhPDp7yab@D2bY6HjNj1LwtTpI7qFWJseM3C5B9@Br/A48Xl3bofAYfG3e4da6P4IWHeLk4O4nMtJDQkgAMJTL16py3IRmYKhh/eHyywvQqlhjf7vlkUz@yWlXj1cF0CtKIZBT4zUa6JWMl4Rv1/iNaS0iVVC6b/CYfEqmQlvHuZ1EqT7cmGW2nkdfTj97g1ecraTmD1QwuZ7BcwveyP0UOH1xl6lNcMhaNE2Wl@T9FrM/Fy50yNlV@F9Zw5b06/fwJPd0fv0Ru0J9GjmhYi61NX353V6ZETvWbsTrNXrzI0ZH30yy7f5nJyKVCunBSXNOl7N1BkcLZ15osuQLkvngWW02x5fPY5RS7@ErPc9PL58GL4ty1mMShASPnzEPy8C8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>46</s> 42 bytes

```hs
p n=sum[mod(product[1..i-1]^2)i|i<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0Ahz7a4NDc6Nz9Fo6AoP6U0uSTaUE8vU9cwNs5IM7Mm00YXxM@Ljf2fm5iZZ1tQlJlXolKVWQASNTQwiNXITSxQKFCAcTX/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>197</s> 165 bytes

Removed the need for the import math by checking every divisor of i besides i itself, though mathematically only checking up to the square root is required.

```
def c(x):
    p=0
    for i in range(2,x+1):
        P=1
        for d in range(1,i):
            if i%d==0 and d!=1:
                P=0
        p+=1*P
    return p
```

Original:

```
import math
def c(x):
    p=0
    for i in range(2,x+1):
        P=1
        for d in range(1,round(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if i%d==0 and d!=1:
                P=0
        p+=1*P
    return p
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can golf this quite a bit by removing some whitespace, and I think you're allowed to use a lambda instead of a function if that'd be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 2 bytes

```
¡Ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBbCIsIiIsIsKhx48iLCIiLCIxXG4yXG41Il0=) - test cases only

This is the same as the 3 byte answer below except the length is taken by the `l` flag rather than an `L` element.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
¡ǏL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67IiwiwqHHj0wiLCI74oCgLCkiLCIyMDAiXQ==)

```
¡  # Factorial
Ǐ  # Prime factorization - list of distinct prime factors
L  # Length of that list
```

Direct port of [Dennis's 05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94364/17216), which is the accepted answer, so one would infer that it meets the challenge's specifications.

The element `†` could be considered a "prime-counting function", even though it counts the distinct prime factors of the input, not the primes less than or equal to the input. The solution using that built-in is **2 bytes**:

```
¡†
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67IiwiwqHigKAiLCI74oCgLCkiLCIyMDAiXQ==)

```
¡  # Factorial
†  # Number of distinct prime factors
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ɾ⟑‹¡²$%;∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67Iiwiyb7in5HigLnCocKyJCU74oiRIiwiO+KAoCwpIiwiMjAwIl0=)

With no factorization built-ins, instead using Wilson's theorem:

```
ɾ  # Inclusive One Range (from 1 to input)
⟑  # Apply lambda to each individual list item:
‹  # Subtract 1
¡  # Factorial
²  # Square
$  # Swap 
%  # Modulo - this will be (n-1)!² % n
;  # Close lambda
∑  # Sum
```

With the `r` flag this is **8 bytes**: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiyoAobuKCtGAgPT4gYOKCtG7OuyIsIsm+4p+R4oC5wqHCsiU74oiRIiwiO+KAoCwpIiwiMjAwIl0=)
With the `rs` flags this is **6 bytes**: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBcnMiLCIiLCLJvuKfkeKAucKhwrIlIiwiIiwiMFxuMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNlxuN1xuOFxuOVxuMTBcbjExXG4xMlxuMTNcbjE0XG4xNVxuMTZcbjE3XG4xOFxuMTlcbjIwXG4yMVxuMjJcbjIzXG4yNFxuMjVcbjI2XG4yN1xuMjhcbjI5XG4zMFxuMzFcbjMyIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```
n=input()
s=p=i=1
while i<n:p*=i*i;i+=1;s+=p%i
print~-s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBLbsMgEN1zihFVFYg/srOq7HCMrqLIchqSjDQFBLhRsuiyB@gRexEXGncHb@bN@7hbvFizmZ/e7BHNWb2@MHx31kdAW4ZbKNOPHfUJBjRuikJ2cCZ7GAmiDrEHr@PkDeiPkURGJBuGw4QU0YRhqP9IoBZ2D9ZpI3heDLW78ZJfuayvHqMWnnM@G7XIsKCcQtWy6wVJA25N59YK19hjodo@FMo9I3MeTfyswpy4u7ar2r3sIbmu3RgvSTxoH0VTwmqV8Ltq2Ml6IEDztxRiitwxIEV1cIRR8IpLBngCSjZJbjcdUKGIQeaZzPOjOWuRVAXtmr0sH6@kW7Qynfq/a6e4xArRCyOLFfx8fUO2kcOnRh54Dy63Mzw6H4alm@wi27h3kCa112THo3AZvat2bqpN0/wC)

A programification of the below. The Python 3 equivalent is [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##NVBdjsIgEH7nFBOSjWBr07pvrZzEGFIj6iQsEJim0QPsAfaIe5EuaPeNmfn@@MKD7t59LvgVfCRAX6dHqvPELuYKGl2YSMgebtafRwtkEg0QDU3RvQam9XlCS@iS1s0LDmrlDeCDcYIXXGrCg9d85rKZI5IRkXO@OIWOxGoiWVLtEBSqjs13tAbw4PqwVbjFASvVDalS4QNZiIWV5JIljl2/605ygBy7CSPdc4ZkIom2hs0m75@qZVcfwQK6FyjRBV3PwCrbpGCRBN9xyQCvYHNaKw/7HmylLIPCc4UXR3czorjaY3uS9fuVfatOZql/XT/R@rtEUThZbeD3@wdKjNJBLua9HyCUkvS7dK3XikqKEuPZQ7400Vg/XkQo26fqlna3b9s/).

Note that although [xnor's recursive answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94385/17216) outgolfs this at **45 bytes**, it cannot handle an input of `999` or greater, due to Python's recursion limit: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BTsMwEEX3PsWoFYqnToPdFUrrY7CCLgJJimV3bNlGqDkAB@CIXCTYQqzYzf9f72nCLb95OqzbVz8auujHB2auwccM6ZbWWbvh@jIOQK3Vqg1a9XRvYaARwp0VMy@9KP3O7iyui5Zs9hEcGKp4l3Jx9gycdl0KzmS@2W@QgZnBTcQdng49OKEdg8pR5eJAl4kbytw9yTO2v5c6o1BYVJVd@j@7f8/dRzR54s0zNXgs@6LV8f@ccuSEooHvzy9oRI3leURc5V5JKX8A) - this limit can be increased, though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BboMwDIbvPIXVaSJuKCPtZYXmMXbaemAF2gjjoCTVVB5gD7BH3IuwsGqn@WDZ/vV/tsdbuFjezg8n2xg@65fnxAyjdQH8zVdLyn0bXHu6Om8skxlMEKr4DZw7TfXw3tTAWa9VNmpV8lMPNTcwPvayE3Eu43zdr3ucJ10knXVAYPhODnFnmQBpyv1IkbzarDAB0wG1LAgP2xJIakpg8fHiczWfW2E4CHotjpjdK3VEqTCiFu9U/tHtNeQfzoRWpG@cYhX1Savqv@yDE4wyhe/PL0jl0sbjEXFWu2JfbNQu/vwD)

This 55 byte solution can go well beyond that. For example, all inputs up to `3000`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBLbsMgEN1zihFVFYg/stNNZYdjdBVFyGlwMhIFBLhRsuiyB@gRexEXEncHb@bN@7hrPFuzmZ/e7RHNSby9Evxw1kdAW4ZrKNOPHNUIEo2bIuMdnLQ9DBqiCrEHr@LkDajPQbOMcCLlYUId0QQp6zsJxMLuwTplGM2LoXZXWtIL5fXFY1TMU0pnIxYZEoQTKFpyOaNWgFvTubXANfZYiLYPhXDPSJxHE7@qMCfuru2qds97SK5rN8RzEg/KR9aUsFol/CYaMloPGtDcl0JMkTsCWug6OI2R0YpyAjiCTjY132460IXQBDLPZJ4fzEmxpMr0rtnz8vFKukXL06n/u3aKS6wQPTO8WMHv9w9kGzl8auSB9@ByO/LRuZRLN9lFtnHrIE1qr7Qdjsxl9Cbaualemqb5Aw)

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```
lambda n,p=1:sum([(p:=p*i*i)%-~i for i in range(1,n)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxLTsMwEIDhfU4xqoTiaR6yywY5@CRtFkFNYaTJxLJdoWaBuuIAXKx34CIhASEW7Gbm13z@kl5GuX/wYabBjyFBvMTmdnWHmbvh6diBlN4ZG8@D2itvnd/SlvCueiM4jQEISCB08twrUwq2OE9OZ2vhtSxYHdORxGbAjuvomZLaVBvMgE7AvSjGx50FLhxn36L8iSRJ8V63WP5MpsXC4EKtv5P91cdzql8DpV7lB8mxWfrkTPM/xxSUYJHD5/sH5MW63q7LBXHW1U7rLw) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY49TsNAEIV7n2IUCXkn_pE3BUJr9iSJC6PYMNJ6vNpdC8UFSsUBaGnShJaKc6Sm5STYJIiCbt689z691ze7Cw89H96ps70L4He-PO315jiENrv5vDZ1d7etgVOrpfJDJ9bCKm2XtCS8yp4I2t4BATG4mu8bIVPGCi_tj1EX0Rwwc2BC5z5siVUERpvcW0NBLLIFRkAtmIaFwduVApNoE_2A-Q9MHIRZFxWm50tWmEicUHN3VL_0fgj5o6PQiHjDMZaTP2pZ_rd9cIIxieHr-QXiZJan_fTBy_jDschWRXEW3w)

A lambdafication of the below, taking advantage of the `:=` operator.

Although [xnor's recursive answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94385/17216) outgolfs this at **46 bytes** when ported to Python 3, it still can't handle an input of `999` or greater: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BTsMwEEX3PsWoCMVTp6kNG5TiY7CCLgJJWsvu2LKNUHMADsARuUiwhVixm6@n9zThms@e7tebNz8aOumnB2YuwccM6ZrWWbvh8joOQK3Vqg1a9bTfWxhohHBrxcwLEAVs7dbiumjJZh/BgaHqdymXaM/Aadel4Ezmm90GGZgZ3ETc4eNdD05ox6B6VL040GnihjJ3z/KI7e@ljigUllR1l/6v7t9z9xFNnnjzQg0eCl@0OvzHKUdOKBr4/vyCRtRZnkfEVe6UlPIH) - this limit can be increased: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU9BTsMwELznFasilLhx0pgKqST4F3BCPYTGbq04G8t2Ds0DeABXLr3AAV7UKy_BaUDsYbWa2dmZffswR3_o8XS-vdr1jcI9f9xEqjO99eCOrppa7oS3YjdYp3rUqlM-YcWlyPvgZbY555LruntuakDackYNZyWuVi3U2IC5blOZBCINxLJdtn-qz5EXkewtaFA4G_kQoYxAc507o4PRIluQCJQELTDR5P6mBJ1yHcGkw0lna9yLRKFP9FOxJXSe2JakjIRTk3YswdgJl3pwB_5gB0GqQI2cVb8M0vj75TWmISihAhseh_l_e058-mLr4q7I2Dr8P0M_)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```
def P(n):
 s=p=i=1
 while i<n:p*=i*i;i+=1;s+=p%i
 return~-s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BTsMwEEX3PsWoCMWuSeRkVSWdO7BhBV0g6rQjmbFlu6qaBUsOwBG5SLCFWLGbr6//5v9wy2fPw3r35o/EJ3zaCXoPPmZIt7Qe7QyPktUoIGFAwl7A9UzOAu15DFukLU2ksZ@SxnBPAqLNl8gfbVoXNGL2ERwQV1iXcvlQSA5dl4KjLDftRgmgGZxl6dR@GMFpdAJqjmsuvvLJSuIs3bM5qIffqz8o3ddSNbuMf3R/yd01UrayeeFGTcVfSrX/dsqxjNINfH9@QaOrrCuVWk07GPMD) - Python 2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xTgMxEEV7n2IUhNaOsytvaNBu5g5pqCAFIt5kJDO2bEdRtqDkAByRiyy2EBXdfH39N/@HWz57flju3vyR@IRPj4Leg48Z0i0tRzvBXrIaBCQMSNgLuJ7JWaAdD2GNtKaRNPZj0hjuSUC0@RL5o03LjEZMPoID4grrUi4fCsmh61JwlOWqXSkBNIGzLJ3abQdwGp2AmuOai698spI4S/dsDmrze/UHpftaqmbn4Y/uL7m7RspWNi/cqLH4c6n23045llG6ge/PL2h0lXWlUotpt8b8AA) - Python 3

Based on [miles's answer to "Is it a super-prime?"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/130390/is-it-a-super-prime/141516#141516).

This exploits [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) and Python's arbitrary precision integers to count primes. At each iteration of the loop, with \$i\in[2,n]\$, it calculates \${(i-1)^2}!\pmod i\$. This \$\equiv 1\$ when \$i\$ is prime and \$\equiv 0\$ otherwise. The squaring is done to compensate for the fact that \$4\$ is the only exception, with \$(4-1)!\equiv 2\pmod 4\$, but \$(4-1)^2!\equiv 0\pmod 4\$. Note that squaring also changes the modulus from \$-1\$ to \$1\$ for prime \$i\$.

If not for the exception at `i=4`, we could have done

```
while i<n:p*=i;i+=1;s+=-p%i
```

For 1 byte less, because Python returns a positive result when taking a negative number modulo a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ü:÷/
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9a3af62f&i=3)

Same approach as many other answers. This is a packed stax program which unpacks to the following 5 bytes:

```
|F:F%
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7CF%3AF%25&i=3)

## Explanation

```
|F    # factorial of input
  :F  # distinct prime factors
    % # length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Êk â Ê
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ymsg4iDK&input=NQ)

```
Êk â Ê     :Implicit input of integer
Ê          :Factorial
 k         :Prime factors
   â       :Deduplicate
     Ê     :Length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
wƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT13JUM2JTkxJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTAwJmZsYWdzPUw=)

Port of Dennis's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
wƑ  # Implicit input
w   # Factorial of input
 Ƒ  # Unique prime factors
    # Implicit output of length
```