# Generate strong primes

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, primes

> [In number theory, a strong prime is a prime number that is greater than the arithmetic mean of the nearest prime above and below (in other words, it's closer to the following than to the preceding prime).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime)

Given an input integer, `n`, where `n >= 0`, your task is to generate the first `n` strong primes. For example, the sixth, seventh, and eighth primes are 13, 17, and 19, respectively:

```
(13 + 19) / 2 < 17
```

Therefore, 17 is a strong prime.

#### Input

- an integer

#### Output

- if `n` is 0

  - program: output nothing
  - function: return an empty array
- if `n` is greater than `0`

  - program: output the first `n` strong primes, each on its own line
  - function: return an array containing the first `n` strong primes

#### Test cases

```
0
[]

4
[11, 17, 29, 37]

7
[11, 17, 29, 37, 41, 59, 67]

47
[11, 17, 29, 37, 41, 59, 67, 71, 79, 97, 101, 107, 127, 137, 149, 163, 179, 191, 197, 223, 227, 239, 251, 269, 277, 281, 307, 311, 331, 347, 367, 379, 397, 419, 431, 439, 457, 461, 479, 487, 499, 521, 541, 557, 569, 587, 599]
```

See also: [Strong primes on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A051634)

Comment: *output n strong primes* - Any n strong primes or the first n strong primes? A few test cases/examples of corresponding inputs and outputs would a nice addition to the challenge.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: I've updated the spec; added a link to OEIS, as well.

Comment: Does it really have to be a newline as delimiter?

Comment: @Titus: Yes it does.

Comment: is it an "and" or an "or" in the spec?  "output and return" or "output, or return"??

Comment: @WillNess: Output if a program, return if a function.

Comment: @WheatWizard: No; from your own comment: "not weak is different than strong". Also, that task is to determine *whether or not* an input, `n`, is a weak prime (but it's yours, so you know that).

Comment: @ZachGates Its the difference between less than and greater than. Just because not weak is not the same as strong does not mean this is not a dupe.  This is a minuscule difference and definitely not a large enough one to warrant its own question.

Answer (score 13):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
↑§foẊ<Ẋ-tİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxEPL0/If7uqyAWLdkiMbCv7//29iDgA)

-1 byte thanks to H.PWiz.

### Explanation

```
↑§foẊ<Ẋ-tİp  Input is n.
         İp  The infinite list of primes.
      Ẋ-     Take pairwise differences,
   oẊ<       then pairwise comparisons.
        t    Frop the first element from İp
 §f          and filter the rest using the result of oẊ<Ẋ-.
↑            Take first n elements of this list.
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxEPL0/If7uqyAWLdkiMbCv7//29iDgA), but a bit more boring

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Æp+ÆnH<ȧÆP
3Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW4H24bY8D5sTyw@3BXAZH25X/v//v4k5AA)

### Explanation

```
Æp+ÆnH<ȧÆP  Helper link. Input: k
Æp          Prime less than k
  +         Plus
   Æn       Prime greater than k
     H      Halve
      <     Less than k?
       ȧ    Logical AND
        ÆP  Is k prime?

3Ç#  Main link. Input: n
  #  Find n matches
3Ç     Call the helper link on 3, 4, 5, ...
```

Comment: I discovered an alternative and thought it might be worth mentioning it: `Æp+Æn<ḤȧÆP`

Answer (score 6):

## Java <s>182</s> <s>167</s> 153 bytes

### Second version

Thank's to Roman Gräf for saving 29 bytes!

```
n->{int s[]=new int[n],i=1,p=i,q=i;while(n>0)if(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(++i).isProbablePrime(n.MAX_VALUE)){if(p>(i+q)/2)s[--n]=p;q=p;p=i;}return s;}
```

#### ungolfed

```
int[] strongPrimes(Integer n) {
        int[] strongPrimes = new int[n];
        int i=1;
        int p1=i; //last prime
        int p2=i; //2 primes ago
        while(n>0) if(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(++i).isProbablePrime(n.MAX_VALUE)) { //increment i and if prime
            //System.out.println("p1:"+p1+" i:"+i+" p2:"+p2);
            if(p1>(i+p2)/2) strongPrimes[--n]=p1; //if the previous one was strong
            p2=p1;
            p1=i;           
        }       
        return strongPrimes;        
    }
```

#### General

I don't think I can get it any smaller without help. Doesn't anyone now of an other build in function to check for primes?

#### concerns

technically there is 2^(-2^31) chance that `isProbablePrime(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` returns true on a non prime but this doesn't happen for an integer.

It also outputs the numbers in reverse order but I didn't see anything about the order in which the primes should be outputted but that's an easy fix (although it could cost some bytes)

Comment: `int[]s(int n){int s[]=new int[n],i=1,p=i,q=i;while(n>0)if(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(++i).isProbablePrime(n.MAX_VALUE)){if(p>(i+q)/2)s[--n]=p;q=p;p=i;}return s;}` without changing any code this should be a bit shorter

Comment: RE: your concern about writing a function: it is acceptable so long as not explicitly ruled otherwise. (I'll leave it to the Java golfers to see if you can golf it!)

Comment: @RomanGräf thank's I'll update it apparently I forgot to remove some white-space and I din't think of defining the variables like that. But "int n" doesn't work because of "n.MAX_VALUE"

Comment: if you want you can use a lambda `n->{...}` that fits into a `Function<Integer,int[]>`

Comment: @RomanGräf does that still count?

Comment: As far as i know yes. i use it myself a lot. I have a look for the relevant meta post. just switch your lang to java 8

Comment: @RomanGräf how about this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/java-function-literals?

Comment: I had [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/56341) one but it is relatively clear if you search meta for lambda

Comment: `n.MAX_VALUE` (which is equivalent to `-1>>>1`) can be replaced with `50` (upper bound for `BigInteger`s with less than 100 bits) (-9 bytes), `if(p‌​>(i+q)/2)` can be replaced with `if(2*p>i+q)`(-2 bytes).

Comment: You can test by dividing. `int a=i; for(;i%--a>0;); if a>1(...`

Comment: Perhaps you can manually check primes to save bytes. [Here is the relevant Java Tip for primes.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100149/52210) Not sure if this saves bytes when using `BigIntegers` though.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The code doesn't actually use the BigIntegers for anything other than the primality check.

Comment: @JollyJoker Ah, you're right. In that case the byte-count can be lowered to **133 bytes**, like this: [`n->{int s[]=new int[n],i=1,p=i,q=i,j,t;while(n>0){for(j=2,t=++i;j<t;t=t%j++<1?0:t);if(t>1){if(p>(i+q)/2)s[--n]=p;q=p;p=i;}}return s;}`](https://tinyurl.com/yd4lb4qx).

Comment: @KevinCrujissen 118 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVBBasMwELznFUugIBFLTUOhB9WGPqC55Bh8UB25XdeWFUlOCMZvd7d2j8mpEKFl0WhHM6NKn7RonbHV4XvExrU@QkWY7CLW8s17fQlqUdQ6BHjXaPsFANpofKkLA9vf4wTscygYdQhcETZQ0Q5RRyxgCwFSGK3I@mlkn6fWnCeazRNMnxKXYnKk0ur8hbVhNlvzvmw90@lqhQofhNDZWnGFJdOvG95TdxnD1ZE/bnjYC2Hz1KkjFT2lhsGb2HkLQQ2jmr247qMmL3@WTi0eoKFAbBc92k/yr/mcZncJ0TSy7aJ0dBVry@Z/kLGdh1mQBVtzPkW9SliKW2t5m3RN5fkuKi/3yfIvmWExjD8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @JollyJoker [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##vVDRasMgFH3vV1wKAyXRdWUwmDNjH7C@9LHkwaVmu1lirJqWEvLtmUv22D4NKl4uHu/xnGOljoq1Vptq/z1iY1sXoIoY7wLW/M05dfZiUdTKe3hXaPoFAJqgXakKDZvf4wTscihI7OCpiNgQK24fVMACNuBBwmhY1k8ju1wafZpoJk9RPqRWYnqIpcTpC2tNTLaifdk6omSSoMA7xlS2ElRgSdTLmvYHSWxGMDnQ@zV99TvGTC7tsxXxJTEMTofOGfBiGMVsxXYfdbTy5@jY4h6amIdsg0PzGe0rOofZnn3QDW@7wG28CrUh8zfw0M7DxPOCrCidkl4kLNm1tbxOuqTyeBOVp9tk@ZfMsBjGHw) (Only golfed your last `if`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>106</strike> 103 bytes

**Edit:** -3 bytes thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```python
n=input()
a=2;b=i=3
while n:
 i+=2
 if all(i%k for k in range(3,i)):
 	if i+a<b*2:print b;n-=1
	a,b=b,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoMwDADQs/2KXIR2VtB60@VjEtAZLLGUytjXd72800u/ct4aalUUTU@xzhCGjVFwMd9T4g66GpABQ/MAitFKf8FxZ7hAFDLpZ7eLF@fa61qRgd78CmvKogV40xFn05FnZC@1ztP0Bw)

Quite straight forward. Loop through all prime numbers keeping track of the two last primes. When a new prime is found, we check if the previous prime is a strong prime, and then update the two primes kept track of. This is done until n strong primes have been found.

Comment: `(i+a)/2<b` means `i+a<b*2` ([105 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEbhdTzFbAraWEh0l3YOo5A0P5GJiKH09NZu3urj5W/dT3GtCUPyVbVRwUZ21iuwV58daSVZFGFk17tRSEnjdtB2FjoIQiXIe9Xewpjuhk4whle8uyUXSKX4lAfPavh/o0Vr8zT9AA))

Comment: You can reorder them a bit: `a=2;b=i=3` ([103 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoMwDADQs/2KXIR2VtB60@VjEtAZLLGUytjXd72800u/ct4aalUUTU@xzhCGjVFwMd9T4g66GpABQ/MAitFKf8FxZ7hAFDLpZ7eLF@fa61qRgd78CmvKogV40xFn05FnZC@1ztP0Bw))

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>81</s> 66 bytes

```
Select[Partition[Prime@Range[#^2],3,1],Apply[#+#3<2#2&]][[;;#,2]]&
```

*thanx to @Marthe172 for -15 bytes*

Comment: -15 bytes: `Select[Partition[Prime@Range[#^2],3,1],Apply[#+#3<2#2&]][[;;#,2]]&`

Comment: You could use [Martin's answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131505/56656) to make this way shorter.

Comment: @WheatWizard you could use Martin's answers any way you like

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 25 bytes

```
.f&P_Z>yZ+fP_ThZefP_TUZQ3
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.f%26P_Z%3EyZ%2BfP_ThZefP_TUZQ3&input=4&debug=0)** or **[Check out the test Suite!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.f%26P_Z%3EyZ%2BfP_ThZefP_TUZQ3&input=4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A4%0A7%0A47&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

Quite happy with this golf given that Pyth kind of lacks prime built-ins.

```
.f&P_Z>yZ+fP_ThZefP_TUZQ3    Full program. Note that Q means input.

.f                     Q3    First Q inputs with truthy results, starting at 3 and counting up by 1.
          fPThZ              First prime after the current number.
               efP_TUZ       The last prime before the current number.
         +                   Sum.
      >yZ                    Is the current number doubled higher than the sum?
  &P_Z                       And is the current number prime?
                             Output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 17 bytes

```
⌠;D;⌐P@P+½@P>⌡╓♂P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9hY3R1YWxsef//4oygO0Q74oyQUEBQK8K9QFA@4oyh4pWT4pmCUP//NA)

Explanation:

```
⌠;D;⌐P@P+½@P>⌡╓♂P
⌠;D;⌐P@P+½@P>⌡╓    first n values (starting with k=0) where:
  D    P             (k-1)th prime
   ;⌐P@ +            plus (k+1)th prime
         ½           divided by 2
 ;        @P>        is less than kth prime
               ♂P  primes at those indices
```

Comment: [tag:feature-request]: `P` maps on a list

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Actually has a GitHub repo. Make an issue there.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the meaning of the comment then :p (like, "this would've been shorter if behavior like other commands existed in this one too"...probably it was a fail...)

Answer (score 2):

### C++, 334 bytes, 318 with MSVC

-1 byte thanks to Mr.Xcoder
-1 byte thanks to Zacharý

With the MSVC compilation, you don't need to include the `cmath` header yourself, it compiles without

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
typedef std::vector<int>v;v p{2};int i(int t){int m=sqrt(t)+2,i=2;for(;i<m;++i)if(t%i<1)return 0;return 1;}void n(){int l=p.back()+1;while(!i(l))++l;p.push_back(l);}auto s(int m){if(!m)return v();n();n();v r;while(r.size()!=m){if((p[0]+p[2])/2<p[1])r.push_back(p[1]);p.erase(p.begin());n();}return r;}
```

### tsh and Mr.Xcoder answer : 131 bytes

tsh rewrote the answer in 139 bytes ( -195 ), and Mr.Xcoder golfed it more with 131 bytes

```cpp
int N,t,o,a,b,i;void n(){t=++N;for(o=2;++o<t;)if(t%o<1)n();}void s(int m,int*r){b=N=t=5;for(;i<m;)if(a=b,b=t,n(),b+b>a+t)r[i++]=b;}
```

[Mr.Xcoder TIO Link](https://tio.run/##JY5BbsMgEEX3PsVIVSS7UKmN2hXgI/gCkReASYQUDxaM24Xls7uDs4D5g/77fL8sHw/vjyMiwSBJJmmlk1H9pjgBtt1GRohB3VNuk7kqIZIm1cV7S5ekvzp2qP30lrZGzJLv99xtzgyGzM8Jqqjnk7HGSWdIMiWdcL0V1OVbFGI0Tu3HW0T/XKegYyqUg537Zi0RH4B2DmWxPkChSTXnRzZyCmwNQF1RsfARoe9futaADAYw/NXlhmN9Li1KyF2V3AzOzpFdn4qHZhS4zSuW89JKoDVwxbHOgNOzkjufHGjNyFyzN8f39R8)

First version ungolfed :

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
typedef std::vector<int> v;
v p{2};
//Tells if a number is prime or not
int i(int t) {
    int m = sqrt(t) + 2, i = 2;
    for (;i < m;++i)
        if (t%i < 1)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
//Push back the next prime number
void n() {
    int l = p.back() + 1;
    while (!i(l))
        ++l;
    p.push_back(l);
}
//Generate a list of m strong primes
auto s(int m) {
    if (!m)
        return v();
    n();
    n();
    v r;
    while (r.size() != m) {
        if ((p[0] + p[2]) / 2 < p[1])
            r.push_back(p[1]);
        p.erase(p.begin());
        n();
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by replacing `if(t%i==0)` with `if(t%i<1)`.

Comment: 1. Where are you getting `sqrt` from? 2. I think you can remove the space between `std::vector<int>` and `v`.

Comment: @Zacharý From the vector include file, apparently. It compiles with MSVC, haven't test with GCC, though

Comment: Then place a note about it being MSVC-only, since I've tested on g++, and it doesn't work due to `sqrt`. Also, is that byte count still correct?

Comment: @Zacharý I think it's correct. I used the [byte counter snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/byte-counter-snippet) from code golf meta to do the count

Comment: I said that because your byte count never changed after you removed the space for some reason.

Comment: @Zacharý You're right, it's cause of a whitespace added by mistake

Comment: [almost rewritten](https://tio.run/##JY5BbsMgEEX3PsVIVSW7UCmN2hXgI/gCkReASTRSPFiA24Xls7uDs4D5g/77fL8snw/vjwOpwCCLjNJKJ1H9RpyA2m4rRohB3WNqo7mqqIsSInZ4b8t71F8dW9R@mnNbM2bJ90fqNmcGU8zPSaK5KNSzqpg1TjpTJIPSCddbUbp0QyFG49R@vCH55zoFjTGXFOzcN2tGegDZOeTF@gC5TKo5/7LIKbA1AHUlxcIjQd@/dG0CCQxQ@KvLjcb6nFuSkLoquRyctZFdF8VDMwrc5hXLeXEtoDVwxbHOQNOzkjufFMqaiLlmb47v6z8)

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY5BbsMgEEX3PsVIVSS7UKmN2hXgI/gCkReASYQUDxaM24Xls7uDs4D5g/77fL8sHw/vjyMiwSBJJmmlk1H9pjgBtt1GRohB3VNuk7kqIZIm1cV7S5ekvzp2qP30lrZGzJLv99xtzgyGzM8Jqqjnk7HGSWdIMiWdcL0V1OVbFGI0Tu3HW0T/XKegYyqUg537Zi0RH4B2DmWxPkChSTXnRzZyCmwNQF1RsfARoe9futaADAYw/NXlhmN9Li1KyF2V3AzOzpFdn4qHZhS4zSuW89JKoDVwxbHOgNOzkjufHGjNyFyzN8f39R8), following @tsh's suggestions.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder A function submit should be able to reuse. initialization of `i` should not be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
µNØN<ØN>Ø+;›i¼NØ}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/wzP8bIDY7vAMbetHDbsyD@0BCtXWav7/b2IOAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>114</s> 85 bytes

```
import Data.List
g=(`take`(tails(nubBy(((>1).).gcd)[2..])>>=(\(a:b:c:_)->[b|b-a>c-b])))
```

(anonymous function [courtesy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141444/generate-strong-primes/141501#comment346810_141501) of [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz); I initially thought I must both print and then return, so had a longer code)

(not counting the `g=` bit)

Running it:

```
~> g 7
[11,17,29,37,41,59,67]
```

Comment: @H.PWiz thanks, on all counts!

Comment: Don't need to include `g=`, see [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129555/71256)

Comment: @H.PWiz can I just have the anonymous function by itself? Trying it with the CPP pragma, it didn't work, probably because of the import.

Comment: (like [this](https://tio.run/##BcHBCsIwDADQX8nBQ3JoQC9CYTmIR/9gDpfWoWVdN9Z4EPz3@t5b6zzl3FpatnU3uKop31K1tmgq0MG2p2JwABxN52lE05Qrlk@4fBFRjsTEr/ik/sQ8kEiHd1QffPQPctKHX3Aq0YWBiODc/g))

Comment: You don't need the CPP bit, I was just looking for a post that explained that `g=` wasn't counted.

Comment: I would leave it out of your code, and if you choose to add a TIO link, put it in there. Like [this](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsIwEADQ3a@4weFuSEAXIZAM4tg/qKW9xBJD01iacxD67/G9N9dlzrm1tG6fXeDBwrpLVU7R4iS8zBMKp1yxfP39h4juQpp0DC/qr1oP5JzFJ7LxJpiRlOv94RW7oPxARG3lVMDCtqcicIYIt/YH)

Comment: btw, [hiding the import in the header](https://tio.run/##BcG7CoMwFADQ3a@4YId7hwTsUhAM2AcuUlw6qdSbKDb4qGg6lLbfnp7z4G3oxtF/RAh5es1uaXaBU1FAKH6BnZbn6uDMjmVuNxf0SeWxcTx0DTq244bzSx/fiKgikiR701K5l7ImpRKskGMdm/hOQpX6qwUrI3RNRH5iO0MCy2pnBzvoITr4Pw) also works for some reason. but it's probably against the rules not to count the import anyway.

Comment: The header is just to do things like pretty printing or adding test suites. It doesn't make [this](https://tio.run/##BcG7CoMwFADQ3a@4YId7hwTsUhAM2AcuUlw6qdSbKDb4qGg6lLbfnp7z4G3oxtF/RAh5es1uaXaBU1FAKH6BnZbn6uDMjmVuNxf0SRVg43joGnRsxw3nlz6@EVFFJEn2pqVyL2VNSiVYIcc6NvGdhCr1VwtWRuiaiLyf2M6QwLLa2cEOeogO/g8) 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [SymPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sympy/1.1.1), 118 bytes

Not as short as the classic approach, but I think it's worth posting.

```python
from sympy.ntheory import*
def f(i):
 k=3
 while i:
	if prevprime(k)+nextprime(k)<k*2and isprime(k):i-=1;yield k
	k+=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclNDsIgEEDhdTnFLKGNJqIrlMOYMIQJv6GTKqdHN12@77XBoRY9p@81wz5yG9fCAWsfQLnVzqtw6MFLUkZAtHcBn0AJgYxYyEPreLROGWVUW8Evn/GKq34XB7SfYuhib89BmBxEscTN6vl/hWWinaWXD6XU/AE)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 109 bytes

```
h(n)==(c:=s:=3;r:=[];for i in 5..by 2|prime?(i)repeat(#r>=n=>break;p:=c;c:=s;s:=i;p+s<2*c=>(r:=cons(c,r)));r)
```

ungolf and results

```
f(n)==
   p:=c:=s:=3;r:List INT:=[]
   for i in 5.. by 2|prime?(i) repeat
      #r>=n=>break
      p:=c;c:=s;s:=i;(p+s)/2<c=>(r:=cons(c,r))
   r

(4) -> f 47
   (4)
   [599, 587, 569, 557, 541, 521, 499, 487, 479, 461, 457, 439, 431, 419, 397,
    379, 367, 347, 331, 311, 307, 281, 277, 269, 251, 239, 227, 223, 197, 191,
    179, 163, 149, 137, 127, 107, 101, 97, 79, 71, 67, 59, 41, 37, 29, 17, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 86 bytes

```python
n=input()
u=p=2;v=i=3
while n:
 p*=i;i+=1
 if p*p%i:
	if u+i<2*v:print v;n-=1
	u,v=v,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoQwDEbhtTlFN4KjdWFnMdCa4yj@IDFIm8HT1@7eB0@ffFwSahWGaMnDhworh2QM/tL/wLk5ieR0ZCRMvJDD3qQ9InUty4Q1jBb1hmRnSeb2dMUbm0etvxc)

Uses Wilson's theorem for the primality test.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>181</s> 180 bytes

```
fun f(l:Int):Array<Int>{var a=1
var b=1
var i=0
var c=0
val o=Array(l,{0})
while(l>0){c++
if((1..c).filter{c%it==0}.size==2){if(c-b<b-a){o[i]=b
if(++i>=l)break}
a=b
b=c}}
return o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNLb5wwEL7zK6ZRK9ldQnguYRVWitQeKlXqoe2p6sGwkLhxYGubRA3it29nTDbk0JXKwfPNzDcPM@O73irZHeT9vtcWfokHEQxWquA9XFzAd9PsoO016KHrGn1ohw5apjafOss311qLP1cIt@OD0CDKyCNZPUtZhk7WTiroSxfAlD@GE/ceb6VqmNqGfKxXK0@2jEVBUPOglco2eqzfSVuW4RQY@dSUZcxHpNTn1VV1LvjY/5A/y4qiViu5LRWvdCPuJk@gsSrrafJ0YwfdQT8ddsIKqJUwBr41xn5AlVFDstsPdgN4AR9cg4N1huVe3PPoxvdCdkzoG3P0fbVadjdbDqMH@FGwxcwGSlDS2C8tc/bj91I19EFQAiRw7v@bky6cKPIhyn2ICx@S/GREfirChxT1DPH6dHT6X@E@5IhzxAXiKCRiSCimg7hRis5onVAGQgVRiBzHCR2EEnTEGTriNaGcbJeoJpQqoepJQgf1lFDRhFIlhWsFUUrelLKkGdnWpBIlvSS1QJTF1LNrnCgZFcrImxUF5@4X4FRJ0FozGhsuwjy@4zyPM50XAofaOl7gFoa/UGQL7I1bCBM0vwehDJsjfJcumBX@Oit99lb3j3BtTKOt7LuPWveandE8oBX4JuYH93ZcSk4@qnO2wPafccMYd7ZXZRbH2dLh5C3nHlfWqu650h5fQ7ND6nT4Cw)

### Explained

```
fun f(l: Int): Array<Int> {
    var a = 1 // Lowest prime
    var b = 1 // Middle prime
    var i = 0 // Current prime index
    var c = 0 // Highest prime
    val o = Array(l, { 0 }) // Output array
    while (l > 0) {  // Functions as while true, while skipping for the 0 case
        c++ // Increment the highest prime
        if ((1..c).filter { c % it == 0 }.size == 2) { // Only if it is prime
            if (c - b < b - a) {                       // If it is strongly prime
                o[i] = b                               // Then record it
                if (++i >= l) break                    // If we have all the answers then stop
            }                                     
            a = b                                      // Rotate the primes
            b = c                                      // As above
        }
    }
    return o  // Return the answer
}
```