# ​Cuban​ ​Primes

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, primes

Given a natural number \$n\$, return the \$n\$-th [cuban prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_prime).

#### Cuban Primes

A cuban prime is a prime number of the form

$$p = \frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}$$

where \$y>0\$ and \$x = 1+y\$ or \$x = 2+y\$

#### Details

- You may use 0 or 1 based indexing, whatever suits you best.
- You can return the \$n\$-th prime given the index \$n\$ or the first \$n\$ primes in increasing order, or alternatively you can return an infinite list/generator that produces the primes in increasing order.

#### Test cases

The first few terms are following:

```
(#1-13)   7, 13, 19, 37, 61, 109, 127, 193, 271, 331, 397, 433, 547,
(#14-24) 631, 769, 919, 1201, 1453, 1657, 1801, 1951, 2029, 2269, 2437,
(#25-34) 2791, 3169, 3469, 3571, 3889, 4219, 4447, 4801, 5167, 5419,
(#35-43) 6211, 7057, 7351, 8269, 9241, 10093, 10267, 11719, 12097,
(#44-52) 12289, 13267, 13669, 13873, 16651, 18253, 19441, 19927, 20173
```

More terms can be found on OEIS: They are split up in two sequences, depending on wheter \$x = 1+y \$ or \$x = 2+y\$: [A002407](https://oeis.org/A002407) and [A002648](https://oeis.org/A002648)

Comment: Can we return the first n primes not sorted?

Comment: @J42161217 No, the primes should be in increasing order.

Answer (score 24):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 54 bytes

A full program that prints cuban primes forever.

```javascript
for(x=0;;){for(k=N=~(3/4*++x*x);N%++k;);~k||print(-N)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SKPC1sDaWrMaxMy29bOt0zDWN9HS1q7QqtC09lPV1s621rSuy66pKSjKzCvR0PXTrP3/HwA)

*<sup>NB: Unless you have infinite paper in your printer, **do not attempt to run this in your browser console**, where `print()` may have a different meaning.</sup>*

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>63 61 60</s>  59 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th cuban prime, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,x)=>(p=k=>N%++k?p(k):n-=!~k)(N=~(3/4*x*x))?f(n,-~x):-N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCoMwEEDRvaeYgoUZ07QUXdmO3sAzKFZLjUyClhIQvXqa3V88/tT9urVfPu6rxb6GEEZGuXjiCh0brpqzUqZ2aKgUzafDEDZ8YH4rMp95onqMXB@eSt2E0S4owHB/gMCTochjKEWwJQC9ldXOw3W2b2w7TDfZKdp0iwfaW0r28Ac)

#### How?

This is based on the fact that cuban primes are primes of the form:

$$p_n=\left\lfloor\frac{3n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1,\;n\ge3$$

The above formula can be written as:

$$p_n=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{3n^2+1}{4}\;\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\\
\dfrac{3n^2+4}{4}\;\text{ if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

or for any \$y>0\$:

$$p_{2y+1}=\dfrac{3(2y+1)^2+1}{4}=3y^2+3y+1$$
$$p_{2y+2}=\dfrac{3(2y+2)^2+4}{4}=3y^2+6y+4$$

which is \$\dfrac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}\$ for \$x=y+1\$ and \$x=y+2\$ respectively.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Generates an infinite list.
Saved 4 bytes with *Kevin Cruijssen's* [port of Arnaulds formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/47066).
Saved another 3 bytes thanks to *Grimy*

```
∞n3*4÷>ʒp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8PGMtk8Pb7U5NKvj/HwA)

**Explanation**

```
∞          # on the list of infinite positive integers
 n3*4÷>    # calculate (3*N^2)//4+1 for each
       ʒp  # and filter to only keep primes
```

Comment: You've made a typo in your explanation: "_put a copy of **`N^2+3`** on the stack_" should be `3*N^2`. Also, why the `)` instead of `¯`? Because it's easier to type? And for some reason I have the feeling the `NnN‚3*¬sO‚` can be 1 byte shorter, but I'm not seeing it. A slight equal-byte alternative is `Nn3*DN3*+‚`. But I'm probably just seeing things that aren't there.. ;) Nice answer, so +1 from me.

Comment: Porting [the formula in _@Arnauld_'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/52210) is 12 bytes: [`[Nn3*4÷>Dpiˆ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2i/PWMvk8HY7l4LM023/aw@tT/d81LBLGcj4b2hgAAA) (PS: Your approach with Arnauld's formula is also 12 bytes, but way slower: [`)[Nn3*4÷>ªʒp`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fM9ovz1jL5PB2u0OrTk0q@F/rku75qGGX8n9DAwMA).)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yeah I tend to use `)` partly because I can write it on my keyboard and I also keep forgetting I can use `¯`. Thanks for the explanation correction and the golf :)

Comment: I actually tried to port my answer to 05AB1E, but failed miserably. :D

Comment: Generating an infinite list isn't required, the question allows you to simply [return the n-th cuban prime](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Fa/PGMtk8Pb7VwK/v83NQIA) (-2 bytes).

Comment: Actually, generating an infinite list is more convenient: 9 bytes with [∞n3*4÷>ʒp](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8PGMtk8Pb7U5NKvj/HwA)

Comment: @Grimy: Thanks! I really should have thought to use `∞` with the simplified formula.

Comment: @Grimy: generating an infinite list isn’t just not required, it violates the requirement to take _n_ as input and output the nth item.

Comment: @WGroleau, you might want to throw another eye over the specs ;)

Comment: OK, I'm not used to specs that contradict themselves.   :-)

Comment: @WGroleau I assume you've never developed software professionally then. I'm more concerned when I get specs that _don't_ contradict themselves.

Comment: Retired from that after nearly forty years.  Yeah, some of the three-hundred-page specs (that should have been fifty pages) did indeed have contradictions.  Those I wrote were less padded and more carefully proofread before release.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>75</s> 73 bytes

```r
n=scan()
while(F<n)F=F+any(!(((T<-T+1)*1:4-1)/3)^.5%%1)*all(T%%(3:T-1))
T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZptWmpdckpmfp1Gho1CcnJiHENCs0Kz@n2cLEtTQ5CrPyMxJ1XCzydN0s3XTTsyr1FDU0NAIsdEN0TbU1DK0MtE11NQ31ozTM1VVBQok5uRohKiqahhbhQAlNLlC/tdypWkYGmj@BwA)

-2 bytes by noticing that I can remove brackets if I use `*` instead of `&` (different precedence).

Outputs the `n`th Cuban prime (1-indexed).

It uses the fact (given in OEIS) that Cuban primes are of the form \$p=1+3n^2\$ or \$4p=1+3n^2\$ for some \$n\$, i.e. \$n=\sqrt{\frac{a\cdot p-1}{3}}\$ is an integer for \$a=1\$ or \$a=4\$.

The trick is that no prime can be of the form \$2p=1+3n^2\$ or \$3p=1+3n^2\$ (*), so we can save 2 bytes by checking the formula for \$a\in\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\$ (`1:4`) instead of \$a\in\{1, 4\}\$ (`c(1,4)`).

Slightly ungolfed version of the code:

```r
# F and T are implicitly initialized at 0 and 1
# F is number of Cuban primes found so far
# T is number currently being tested for being a Cuban prime
n = scan()                       # input
while(F<n){
  T = T+1                        # increment T 
  F = F +                        # increment F if
    (!all(((T*1:4-1)/3)^.5 %% 1) # there is an integer of the form sqrt(((T*a)-1)/3)
     & all(T%%(3:T-1)))          # and T is prime (not divisible by any number between 2 and T-1)
  }
T                                # output T
```

(*) No prime can be of the form \$3p=1+3n^2\$, else \$1=3(p-n^2)\$ would be divisible by \$3\$.

No prime other than \$p=2\$ (which isn't a Cuban prime) can of the form \$2p=1+3n^2\$: \$n\$ would need to be odd, i.e. \$n=2k+1\$. Expanding gives \$2p=4+12k(k+1)\$, hence \$p=2+6k(k+1)\$ and \$p\$ would be even.

Comment: what about avoiding a loop by using an upper bound on the nth Cuban prime?

Comment: @Xi'an I thought about that, but couldn't come up with such a bound. Do you have one?

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <strike>[66](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lDbLSc/vyjaWDnOSN8kVs06z9bIOtNW2To8IzMnNTrTzkAnU9fWKT8/J9UhoCgzNzXQIc1BWzsv1jrNIU9T7T9QLK8kuiDa1Cg29v9/AA)</strike> <strike>[65](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lD7UU@XsXKckb7Jo55uNes8WyPrTFtl6/CMzJzU6Ew7A51MXVun/PycVIeAoszc1ECHNAdt7bxY6zSHPE21/0CxvJLogmhTo9jY//8B)</strike> [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lD7UU@XsbK@ifKjnm41a7f8oug820xbA51MG2WdgKLM3NRAhzQHbe08NbVMbe1Y6zSHPE21/0CJvJLogmhTo9jY//8B)

```
(f=1+⌊3#/4#⌋&;For[n=i=0,i<#,PrimeQ@f@++n&&i++];f@n)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lD7UU@XsbK@ifKjnm41a7f8oug820xbA51MG2WdgKLM3NRAhzQHbe08NbVMbe1Y6zSHPE21/0CJvJLogmhTo9jY//8B)

- [J42161217](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/444852) **-1** by using `⌊ ⌋` instead of `Floor[ ]`
- [attinat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/444860)

  - **-1** by using `⌊3#/4#⌋` instead of `⌊3#^2/4⌋`
  - **-8** for `For[n=i=0,i<#,PrimeQ@f@++n&&i++]` instead of `n=2;i=#;While[i>0,i-=Boole@PrimeQ@f@++n]`

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lD7UU@XsXKckb7Jo55uNes8WyPrTFtl6/CMzJzU6Ew7A51MXVun/PycVIeAoszc1ECHNAdt7bxY6zSHPE21/0CxvJLogmhTo9jY//8B "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online"). Welcome to ppcg. Nice first answer! +1

Comment: Thanks! (Long time lurker.) I couldn't quite parse your existing answer so I wrote my own and it came out a little shorter. I might do a Python one too.

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2D7XyPN1lD7UU@XsbK@ifKjnm41a7f8oug820xbA51MG2WdgKLM3NRAhzQHbe08NbVMbe1Y6zSHPE21/0CJvJLogmhTo9jY//8B "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @attinat I thought Arnauld's formula only worked for n>2 so I didn't start with 0 - although as in your example it works for all n (because it starts 1 1 4 7 13 ... so the primes are 7 13 ...)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>94</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=3,n,x;;System.out.print(x<1?++n+" ":""))for(x=n=i*i++*3/4;~n%x--<0;);}
```

-6 bytes by using [the Java prime-checker of *@SaraJ*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181611/52210), so make sure to upvote her!
-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*. Since the first number we check is `7`, we can drop the trailing `%n` from Sara's prime-checker, which is to terminate the loop for `n=1`.
-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by porting *@Arnauld*'s answer.

Outputs space-delimited indefinitely.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwDIbvPEVDYrIxQA2eHOgTyIXEi/EwJ5ohFAKDYAi@Og7l0qZt/n5fJjrhZffXJHPRNHASCgcLQKFO64eQKcTzCNCV6g6SnOfWUW52o2VKo4VWEmJAiGDqvMPwKGti0qCiwEW35zx5Nzot/LLVflWbC@nD7ZExZDbYe9umdE70EUbKUYw5wXrHP7jqPS/ccMrHic@cqr3lhrPgfjKFUSWJNi@flysI@vdEXxJs83xRHKcv)

**Explanation (of the old 86 bytes version):** *TODO: Update explanation*

Uses the formula of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/52210): \$p_n=\left\lfloor\frac{3n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1,\;n\ge3\$.

```java
v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=3,           //  Loop-integer, starting at 3
          n,x            //  Temp integers
      ;                  //  Loop indefinitely:
      ;                  //    After every iteration:
       System.out.print( //     Print:
        n==x?            //      If `n` equals `x`, which means `n` is a prime:
         n+" "           //       Print `n` with a space delimiter
        :                //      Else:
         ""))            //       Print nothing
    for(n=i*i++*3/4+1,   //   Set `n` to `(3*i^2)//4+1
                         //   (and increase `i` by 1 afterwards with `i++`)
        x=1;             //   Set `x` to 1
        n%++x            //   Loop as long as `n` modulo `x+1`
                         //   (after we've first increased `x` by 1 with `++x`)
             >0;);}      //   is not 0 yet
                         //   (if `n` is equal to `x`, it means it's a prime)
```

Comment: I don't really think it's feasible, but another way of finding the cuban primes uses this formula: `v->{for(int n=7,i=3,p,x,d,r=0;;i+=++r%2*3,n+=i,System.out.print(x>1?x+" ":""))for(x=n,d=1;++d<n;x=x%d<1?0:n);}`, maybe someone can use this to golf? I couldn't.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You can golf yours a bit more by removing the unused `,p` and changing `i+=++r%2*3,n+=i` to `n+=i+=++r%2*3`, but then I'll still end up at 106 bytes. Using Java 11's `String#repeat` with prime-regex is 105 bytes: `v->{for(int n=7,i=3,r=0;;n+=i+=++r%2*3)if(!"x".repeat(n).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+"))System.out.println(n);}`.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it wasn't much golfable despite my (now obvious) mistakes. Thanks for giving it a ride ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Maybe also good to know for you, but there is apparently a shorter prime-check loop in Java. See my edit and SaraJ's prime-check answer.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the last `%n` isn't required, is it?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, in this case it's indeed not necessary, since we start at `n=7`. With a general prime check the trailing `%n` is still required for `n=1` though, since `1%x` for `x>=2` will always result in `1`. So without the trailing `%n` the loop won't terminate for `n=1`.

Comment: [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwDIbvPEWzxGRzgBo9OdEn0IuJF@NhDjBDLIYNgjH46nMolzZt8/f7CtnKqEjvTpXSGNhLje8AQKPN6lyqDA7DCNBWOgVFT0NrmfC7PvDFWGm1ggMgJODaaPvOq5r6NOhkGWLYCXF8GZs94qqx8bP2F9ptFjvOkRMga0IYGxJdgomeas6ny9lKzLcfnHRRJJjonRg4z@Zaes6I@8k8vCo9Wv/ydr6AZH9PjBXFpixHxd59AQ), trying to use some of @Arnauld's techniques.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 83 bytes

```
(t=1;While[Length[l=Select[Join@@Array[{(v=3#^2+1)+3#,v}&,t++],PrimeQ]]<#];Sort@l)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PE1tA6PCMzJzXaJzUvvSQjOsc2ODUnNbkk2is/M8/BwbGoKLEyulqjzNZYOc5I21BT21hZp6xWTadEWztWJ6AoMzc1MDbWRjnWOji/qMQhR1PtP1Awr0TBIT3a1Cj2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
²×3:4‘
ÇẒ$#Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//wrLDlzM6NOKAmArDh@G6kiQjw4f//zU)

Based on [@Arnauld’s method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/42248). Takes n on stdin and returns that many Cuban primes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 83 bytes

This solution will output the n-th Cuban prime with the added benefits of being fast and remembering all previous results in the symbol f.

```
(d:=1+3y(c=1+y)+3b c;e:=If[PrimeQ@d,n++;f@n=d];For[n=y=b=0,n<#,e;b=1-b;e,y++];f@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxC8IwFATg3V8hFKQlEa3Fpc@HmQQ3FbeQIUmTNEOeULrk18c61ungu7uk59ElPUerS8BSDz22rMu1XSI3rDNbC67Hu5ePKSb3FAMnxsALwkHB7TNJwowGj5wuFXdgsN0bcDwzppZV1ezKcqRZvmOKFGQ4iJem4OT5pJSCzboUP/1Dv8KrV1C@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>[110](https://tio.run/##RcuxDsIgEADQ3a@4xQSwSVOqi4n@iNNpodLAHTkxwa/H1sX9vfwpT6axNS@cIBQnhTm@IKTMUsxuvqgKngUqBIKEWUVM9wmBzsNhNGSM7ftj9@A3FaU1BA8Yo6r75beWbQnS7JTtqtZIE9TroNstS1gHuVrUvL4Nhz8@Wd3aFw)</strike> <strike>[108](https://tio.run/##RcuxDsIgEADQ3a@4xQSwSVOqi4n@iNNpodLAHTkxwa/H1sX9vfwpT6axNS@cIBQnhTm@IKTMUsxuvqgKngUqBIKEWUVM9wmBzsNhNGSM7ftj9@A3FaU1BA8Yo6r75beWbQnS7JTtqtZIE9TroNstS1gHuVrUvL4Nhz8@Wd3aFw)</strike> [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##RcuxDsIgEADQ3a@4xYTDJo1UFxO/xDigAl4DdwQxwa/H1sX9vfypT@Gpd18kAVVXqkh8AaUspepNOKsGXgo0IIZks4o23R4W@LTfTZq1NuN4GO7y5qoMIpAHG6Nq2/nX5rUVy8EpMzRE7JdcaLHsWlVhCauivzoavPb@BQ)

Similar method to my [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185580/82115) (i.e. `isPrime(1+⌊¾n²⌋) else n++`)
 using [this golfed prime checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143305/82115) and returning an anonymous infinite generator

```python
from itertools import*
(x for x in map(lambda n:1+3*n**2//4,count(2)) if all(x%j for j in range(2,x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcuxDsIgEADQ3a@4xYTDJo1UFxO/xDigAl4DdwQxwa/H1sX9vfypT@Gpd18kAVVXqkh8AaUspepNOKsGXgo0IIZks4o23R4W@LTfTZq1NuN4GO7y5qoMIpAHG6Nq2/nX5rUVy8EpMzRE7JdcaLHsWlVhCauivzoavPb@BQ)

- [mypetlion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/444863?noredirect=1) **-2** because arguably anonymous generators are more allowed than named ones
- **-6** by starting `count` at 2 <sub>+1</sub> so that the `and x>1` in the prime checker I borrowed is unnecessary <sub>-7</sub>

Comment: The answer going into a variable is usually not considered a valid form of "output". Could you rework your answer so that the result is either output to stdout or returned by a function?

Comment: since anonymous functions are allowed, and the challenge explicitly allows an infinite generator, I've removed `g=`. I had only included it in the first place because it allowed a quick visual on TIO with `print(next(g) for i in range(52))`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Adapted from [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/58974). 1-indexed.

```
@µXj}f@Ò(X²*¾
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLVYan1mQNIoWLIqvg&input=OA)

1 byte saved thanks to EmbodimentOfIgnorance.

Comment: [13 bytes?](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLVYan1mQNIoWLIqvg&input=OA) Not tested thoroughly though.

Comment: Thanks, @EmbodimentofIgnorance. I'd tried that but it didn't work; turns out I'd forgotten the `(`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 124 bytes

```
(require math)(define(f n[i 3])(let([t(+(exact-floor(* 3/4 i i))1)][k(+ 1 i)])(if(prime? t)(if(= 0 n)t(f(- n 1)k))(f n k))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BCsJAEEN/JeAlYylaq0fxQ0oPi87q0HZblxH8@7rqKbzwCMnhOqivmzGkO/IfmPX5sqyYgj@EN42WlBGpM7S9cFRn56yo73D1Oo7znLlFuzvCYCKN9N3ACk2Bolvkkm3SC/wHZ@yRxBlZI6GRQeQ7jpIiK6ewIIK5HFKcDqX6AA)

Returns the n-th cuban prime, 0-indexed.

Uses the formula of [@Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/52210)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 180 bytes

```
[S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S N
S _Duplicate][N
S S N
_Create_Label_OUTER_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top_stack][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3][T  S S N
_Multiply][S S S T  S S N
_Push_4][T  S T S _Integer_divide][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S S S T N
_Push_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top_stack][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][S T   S S T   T   N
_Copy_0-based_3rd][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_if_0][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    S T T   _Modulo][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S S S N
_Jump_to_Label_FALSE_if_0][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_PRINT][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10_(newline)][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][S N
S _Duplicate][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_FALSE][S N
N
_Discard_top_stack][S N
N
_Discard_top_stack][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_OUTER_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Outputs newline-delimited indefinitely.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bU3RCoBACHueX7Ffiziot6Cgzzc3fYzj5tRtvsf5rPva9pVJEgw/QagPFPYAroRnZlVAC0Yn0v6/AEnbLYATfRDVNZE0xlsiS6gb4pzo3od/5gc) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

Port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185595/52210), which also uses the formula from [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/52210): \$p_n=\left\lfloor\frac{3n^2}{4}\right\rfloor+1,\;n\ge3\$.

```
Integer i = 2
Start OUTER_LOOP:
  i = i + 1
  Integer n = i*i*3//4+1
  Integer x = 1
  Start INNER_LOOP:
    x = x + 1
    If(x == n):
      Call function PRINT
    If(n % x == 0):
      Go to next iteration of OUTER_LOOP
    Go to next iteration of INNER_LOOP

function PRINT:
  Print integer n
  Print character '\n'
  Go to next iteration of OUTER_LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 83 bytes

prints the cuban primes forever.

```python
P=k=1
while 1:P*=k*k;x=k;k+=1;P%k>0==((x/3)**.5%1)*((x/3+.25)**.5%1-.5)and print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8A229aQqzwjMydVwdAqQMs2WyvbusI22zpb29bQOkA1287A1lZDo0LfWFNLS89U1VBTC8zT1jMyhYro6plqJualKBQUZeaVaGRr/v8PAA)

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70027/64121) prime generator. For every prime it checks whether an integer y exists that fulfills the equation for either \$x = 1+y\$ or \$x=2+y\$.

$$ p=\frac{(1+y)^3-y^3}{(1+y)-y} = 1 + 3y +3y^2 \Leftrightarrow y = -\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{p-1}{3}}$$

$$ p=\frac{(2+y)^3-y^3}{(1+y)-y} = 4 + 6y +3y^2 \Leftrightarrow y = -1 \pm\sqrt{\frac{p-1}{3}}$$ 
As we only care whether \$y\$ has an integer solution, we can ignore the \$\pm\$ and \$-1\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Grimy*

```perl6
{grep &is-prime,1+|¾*$++²xx*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7vzq9KLVAQS2zWLegKDM3VcdQu@bQPi0Vbe1DmyoqtGr/FydWKqRpaEbHGRnEWv8HAA)

Anonymous code block that returns a lazy infinite list of Cuban primes. This uses [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/76162) to generate possible cuban primes, then `&is-prime` to filter them.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                           }  # Anonymous code block
 grep &is-prime,               # Filter the primes from
                         xx*   # The infinite list
                   ¾*          # Of three quarters
                     $++²      # Of an increasing number squared
                1+|            # Add one by ORing with 1
```

Comment: `1+0+|` can be just `1+|`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 51 bytes

Using [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185568/9288).

```
n->a=0;for(i=1,n,until(isprime(p=3*a^2\4+1),a++));p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxCsMwDAC/IjJZsQxx2k5GeUkIeIiDIFWN677f1XLDcVdzk3DVUYCHhi3zksqnOeFISj/tcjv51ibv01V@zPlY96ePSNl7xGSfxQoMkeC1EFip3cQEYTMUp4g4/g)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 98 chars, 196 bytes

```
r←h w;y;c;v
r←c←y←0⋄→4
→3×⍳∼0πv←1+3×y×1+y+←1⋄r←v⋄→0×⍳w≤c+←1
→2×⍳∼0πv+←3×y+1⋄c+←1⋄r←v
→2×⍳w>c
```

indented :

```
r←h w;y;c;v
r←c←y←0⋄→4
    →3×⍳∼0πv←1+3×y×1+y+←1⋄r←v⋄→0×⍳w≤c+←1
    →2×⍳∼0πv+←3×y+1⋄c+←1⋄r←v
    →2×⍳w>c
```

test:

```
  h ¨1..20
7 13 19 37 61 109 127 193 271 331 397 433 547 631 769 919 1201 1453 1657 1801 
  h 1000
25789873
  h 10000
4765143511
```

it is based on: if y in N, one possible Cuban Prime is

```
S1=1+3y(y+1)
```

the the next possible Cuban Prime will be

```
S2=3(y+1)+S1
```